# How can I unescape HTML entities using Guava?

Tags: java, html, escaping, guava

I can't seem to find the right documentation for this. Apache has an unescapeHtml method and im sure Guava has a similar method.

Comment: Questions like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542550/what-are-the-big-improvements-between-guava-and-apache-equivalent-libraries led me to believe that i can replace my usage of apache libs with guava.

Answer (score 0):

Needing to "manually" unescape anything is usually a strong sign that you are not using a proper tool/framework that will serve your needs at a higher level.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm extracting metadata from HTML pages with the aid of Jsoup/goose. Do you know of another html parser which can do html entity resolution?

Comment: Try asking a question tagged with 'jsoup' and 'goose', then, explaining what you're *really* trying to do here. That (those?) APIs shouldn't make you bring in another third-party library just to do unescaping, which is something they should be good at.