# What is the compare contract?

Tags: java, comparator

My java code threw the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I researched the message on StackOverflow and found several questions that posted their poorly written compare methods, but I was wondering where the contract is written and what exactly does it state regarding what the compare method must do.

Comment: I think you should post some of your code in order to get some real help.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Probable duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11441666/823393).

Comment: From looking at other questions, it seems it would raise that exception if your compare method violates transitivity.

Comment: You should have researched the Javadoc for `java.util.Compare` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [**Java Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) have it

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) ==
>   -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an
>   exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:
>   ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies
>   that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.
>
> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x,
>   y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any comparator that
>   violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The
>   recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that
>   are inconsistent with equals."

Comment: WHo would believe it - API docs for `Comparator` hidden away in the API docs for `Comparator`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: I think only John Skeet could know that.