# Unclear "Comparison method violates its general contract!" in transitive comparator

Tags: sorting, java-8, timsort

In Java8 I have an algorithm I cannot really change that orders a particular structure as follows:

- All elements in category XXX must go to the end of the array (does not matter the order)
- All other elements can have any order

It was implemented like this:

```
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        boolean isXXX1 = "XXX".equals(o1.getCategory());
        boolean isXXX2 = "XXX".equals(o2.getCategory());
        if(isXXX1) {
            return isXXX2 ? 0 : 1;
        } else if(isXXX2) {
            return -1;
        }
        return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
    });
```

Hashcode is created by ReflectionashCode on the PoJo objects, so I do not expect weird collisions.

Occasionally, apparently at random, this piece of code throws IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

I tried to debug it, but even with the same data in debug mode it does not break.
What could be the cause? I dont see any case where the sorting does not respect the contract

Comment: You cannot implement a "does not matter" order. The contract contains a clause that if a<b <-> b<a, so if you run the comparison twice with arguments reversed, the order must stay the same.

Comment: Two objects with different `isXXX` are sorted differently depending on whether compareTo(o1, o2) or compareTo(o2, o1) is called. Your comparisons must be symetric. In other words: when only one of `isXXX1` and `isXXX2` is true, then you must have *some* stable decision on which one should be sorted first. Right now you "randomly" decide based on which one is passed as the first argument.

Comment: Put differently: your comparator must define a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). You could use `System.identityHashCode()` to define a stable order if you don't care about the specifics.

Comment: @daniu the "does not matter" is the business requirement. The function defines an order: it's based on the hashCode

Comment: @JoachimSauer actually if they are both XXX you get 0, meaning equal, which is correct.
If only 1 is XXX, then you get 1 if you put it as first element and -1 if it's the second, as per contract compare(XXX, other) = -compare(other, XXX)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the compare contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765158/what-is-the-compare-contract)

Comment: Right, I must have misread/misthought it somethow ... I can't find any other flaw in that code (apart from maybe annoying but shouldn't-be-causing-this-problem hash collisions). Is there a chance that any of the objects get modified while the list is being sorted?

Comment: your handling in case both of `isXXX1` and `isXXX2` are `true` is probably not consistent with the `equals` method of the class of `o1` and `o2`. This could lead to a problem.

Comment: @cyberbrain: AFAIK it's not a requirement for the `compareTo` of an externaly-specified `Comparator` to be consistent with `equals()`. In fact that requirement would make a `Comparator` significantly less useful. Even for the `compare()` method of `Comparable` consistency is barely a suggestion and not a strict requirement.

Comment: yes it is not consistent with equals, but that's ok according to the doc.
Checked the list is not being edited at the same time, and it has not happened. I wonder if it really was an hashcode collision

Comment: I see that exception probably coming from `java.util.TimSort`, when that merges results of different "runs". TBH I don't understand that algorithm fully, but when you are talking about "the same data in debug mode" do you also mean the same number of list elements in the same original order? To possibly trigger that exception from there, your list has to contain >= 32 elements.

Comment: I can't help wondering why a sort was even considered for this? Since the only requirement is to put "XXX" categories at the end of the list, a simple regrouping would be more efficient than a sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR

*Never use minus as a comparator function*.

Your comparator ends with `return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();`

Unfortunately, developers come up with this idea all the time and for some tests (i.e. with small values), it might seem to work.

The problem is that comparing *arbitrary integer values* (and hash codes may use the entire `int` value range) can lead to overflow, as the distance between two `int` values may be larger than the `int` value range.

The correct idiom would be `return Integer.compare(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());`

There is no problem if a hash collision occurs, as that simply means that the two elements would be treated as equal for this particular sort operation, which is fine if you don’t care about their relative order anyway. In fact, you can treat all elements whose relative order is irrelevant as equal, replacing the last line with `return 0;`.

Or, simplify the entire operation with

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> "XXX".equals(o.getCategory())));
```

Since `Boolean` values are comparable and [its `compareTo` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#compareTo(java.lang.Boolean)) will treat `true` as larger than `false`, it will move the matching elements to the end of the list.

Comment: OH, you are absolutely right. This make sense, never thought of it, I saw a lot of people online (even on this site) using that hashCode bit and nobody pointed out the issue ever. Good catch

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

According to the `Arrays.LegacyMergeSort class`, to cater to "broken"comparators, you can opt to use the legacy merge sort by setting a System property. For my tests described below, this worked.

```
 System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "TRUE");
```

**Details which may allow improving your comparator.**

The following program does not answer the question but it may help find it. It generates random data and then sorts using your comparator.  Then it loops and shuffles the data until an exception is thrown and prints the original list and the list at the time of exception.

- create a record to hold the data.
- Random strings of lengths 4 to 7 are created and added.
- then add some "XXX" values to the list
- continue sorting and shuffling the data until an exception is thrown and print before and after results.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SortingIssue {
    record Info(String getCategory) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getCategory;
        }
    }
    
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Random r = new Random();
        List<Info> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            int len = r.nextInt(4,8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = 0; k <len; k++) {
                sb.append((char)r.nextInt('A', 'Z'+1));
            }
            list.add(new Info(sb.toString()));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            list.add(new Info("XXX"));
        }
        
        
       for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        List<Info> orig = new ArrayList<>(list);
        try {
        list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            boolean isXXX1 = "XXX".equals(o1.getCategory());
            boolean isXXX2 = "XXX".equals(o2.getCategory());
            if(isXXX1) {
                return isXXX2 ? 0 : 1;
            } else if(isXXX2) {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.hashCode() - o2.hashCode();
        });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Original List: " + orig);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("List at exception: " + list);
            break; 
        }
       }
    }
}
```

I did not do extensive tests but I noticed that I could not get an list < 32 elements to throw an exception which just happens to be the minimum merge limit for TimSort.

```
 private static final int MIN_MERGE = 32;
```

Output

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contr
act!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:903)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:520)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1308)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1804)
    at stackOverflow.sandbox.SortingIssue.main(SortingIssue.java:39)
Original List: [PLKRPMX, KAKAZPD, XXX, YVJVMH, FCKDWW, XXX, GQXRTW, XXX, XXX, NZ
PAD, XXX, XXX, XXX, IPPVZL, TLKKCJE, XXX, GHXG, GHPO, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, X
XX, QTRAWN, XXX, XXX, HXKD, UGNV, XXX, RRQP, JVZI]

List at exception: [YVJVMH, TLKKCJE, KAKAZPD, NZPAD, PLKRPMX, FCKDWW, GQXRTW, IP
PVZL, QTRAWN, GHPO, GHXG, HXKD, JVZI, RRQP, UGNV, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, 
XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX, XXX]
```

**Updated**

I found this in the `Arrays.class`.

```
   /**
     * Old merge sort implementation can be selected (for
     * compatibility with broken comparators) using a system property.
     * Cannot be a static boolean in the enclosing class due to
     * circular dependencies. To be removed in a future release.
     */
    static final class LegacyMergeSort {
        @SuppressWarnings("removal")
        private static final boolean userRequested =
            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new sun.security.action.GetBooleanAction(
                    "java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort")).booleanValue();
    }
}
```

Once I set the property, I no longer got the problem.  The decision on which sort to use is made in `Arrays.class` and depends on the property value.

```
 System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "TRUE");
```

Instead of sorting, just separate into lists `with XXX` and `without "XXX"` and add the `"XXX"` list to the end of the other.

```
List<Info> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(
                info -> info.getCategory().equals("XXX") ? "withXXX"
                        : "withoutXXX"),
                map -> {
                    map.get("withoutXXX").addAll(map.get("withXXX"));
                    return new ArrayList<>(map.get("withoutXXX"));
                }));
```

Comment: I can confirm after some looking around, the exception seems to happen only for arrays bigger than 32, as you said.
It never happened for smaller sets (I get any from 1 to 150 elements, but smaller case are way more frequent, and there's always at least 1 XXX, and non-XXX are always at least the same number as XXX, more often more).
So this definetly has something to do with the TimSort implementation. I will probably just change it to split the list into two and merge them later as someone else suggested, but still I'll try to find out why it breaks

Comment: @AlexMarcat Did you notice the property solution?  Apparently `TimSort` was strictly enforcing the comparator so the `Arrays.class` has a work around.   If setting the property isn't viable, I have included one possibility to separate the lists as per my comment on your question. See the example at the end of my answer

Comment: I think, it is worth investigating *why* the comparator is broken, instead of discussing an option to continue with a broken comparator. You may not get an exception with the old sort algorithm, but potentially inconsistent results are not better.

Comment: As someone pointed out, it's actually the hashCode thing. It "generally" works, until you have an overflow! That breaks transitivity