# Debug "Comparison method violates its general contract!"

Tags: java, sorting

I have an own, relatively sophisticated string comparator and a large list of strings (~100 strings, already tried to reduce but then the problem is not reproducible) where sorting them produces the above error when trying to sort with Java 7. I guess, that the rule

```
if a < b and b < c then a < c
```

might be violated. What is the best way to find out a sample which violates the contract?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Have you got *any* unit tests for your comparator?

Comment: Don't reduce the list; reduce the *comparator* instead, stepwise while reproducing the error with the same input set. Then post the *minimal* comparator which still suffers from the problem. At that point, however, it may become obvious to you.

Comment: Post the comparator code.  This type of error can usually be found by inspection.

Comment: @RohitJain For an example code see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364904/debug-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract#comment52365577_18376717

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I did it the brute-force-way: 3 nested loops to compare 3 values with each other and verifying the above rule. Now found a sample where the rule is violated.

Comment: @Buffalo And it goes a little something like this: for (Node node1 : nodes1) for (Node node2 : nodes2) for (Node node3 : nodes3) if (node1.compareTo(node2) < 0 && node2.compareTo(node3) < 0 && node1.compareTo(node3) > 0) alertVioaltionOfContract(node1,node2,node3);

Answer (score 1):

add debug message at start of your compare() method and to equals() / hashcode() methods (you are overriding them right?)

Comment: what is wrong with this reply that you down voted? you would have problematic value in a minute

Comment: The equals and hashcode methods should not be used when using a comparator.

Comment: You are right, that custom comparator might not need them. But it does not hurt to override them.

Comment: Overriding them does not help anything to resolve this particular problem.

Comment: True, that was irrelevant idea. But debug message does.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with a similar problem the only way to deep-dive the problem and find the set of A, b and c that violates the general contract, is to use loops.

Suppose you have a `list` that needs sorting and a custom `comparator` that is violating its contract you can find the objects using something like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j ++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k ++) {
                        Objects a = list.get(i);
                        Objects b = list.get(j);
                        Objects c = list.get(k);
                        if (comparator.compare(a, b) < 0
                                && comparator.compare(b, c) < 0
                                && comparator.compare(a, c) > 0) {
                            System.out.print(("Error...1");
                            System.out.print((a + ", " + i);
                            System.out.print((b + ", " + j);
                            System.out.print((c + ", " + k);
                        }
                        if (comparator.compare(a, b) > 0
                                && comparator.compare(b, c) > 0
                                && comparator.compare(a, c) < 0) {
                            System.out.print(("Error...2");
                            System.out.print((a + ", " + i);
                            System.out.print((b + ", " + j);
                            System.out.print((c + ", " + k);
                        }
                        if (comparator.compare(a, b) == 0
                                && comparator.compare(b, c) == 0
                                && comparator.compare(a, c) != 0) {
                            System.out.print(("Error...3");
                            System.out.print((a + ", " + i);
                            System.out.print((b + ", " + j);
                            System.out.print((c + ", " + k);

                        }
                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have used this method many times before, especially when you are unable to find the logical errors in your coding through inspection.

I also found this answer on another post that has a general class you can use

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35000727/4019094