# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparison

Hi below is my compare method of my comparator. I am not sure what is wrong. I looked up other similar titled questions and answers on stack overflow but not sure what is wrong with my method but I keep getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
public int compare(Node o1, Node o2)
{
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> childMap = orderMap.get(parentID);
    if(childMap != null && childMap.containsKey(o1.getID()) && 
                           childMap.containsKey(o2.getID()))
    {
        int order1 = childMap.get(o1.getID());
        int order2 = childMap.get(o2.getID());

        if(order1<order2) 
            return -1;
        else if(order1>order2) 
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Adding the exception I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

Comment: What line do you get the exception on?

Comment: @tieTYT I think the exception is being thrown from within a collection he's passing this to as a `Comparator`. This comparator looks really unstable, as any modifications to *`orderMap[parentID]`* or the ordering specified in `childMap` will move the items around.

Comment: What is `parentId`'s type?  Are you storing a HashMap within a Map?

Comment: parentID is an Integer

Comment: Similar question is already answered...Check it here
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract

Comment: check out the following link ... similar question has been answered already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract
.

Comment: I have below code that also happened of this exception error:

Comment: @Override
public int compareTo(ActivitiesCourseWebVo another){
 if(this.courseInfo.getCourseEndDate().after(another.courseInfo.getCourseEndDate()))
  return 1;
 else
  return -1;
 
}

Comment: I have solved by using compareTo as i need to take care of same condition.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your `compare()` method is **not *transitive***. If `A == B` and `B == C`, then `A` must be equal to `C`.

Now consider this case:

For `A`, `B`, and `C`, suppose the `containsKey()` method return these results:

- `childMap.containsKey(A.getID())` returns `true`
- `childMap.containsKey(B.getID())` returns `false`
- `childMap.containsKey(C.getID())` returns `true`

Also, consider orders for `A.getId()` != `B.getId()`.

So,

1. `A` and `B` would return `0`, as outer `if` condition will be `false` => `A == B`
2. `B` and `C` would return `0`, as outer `if` condition will be `false` => `B == C`

But, `A` and `C`, could return `-1`, or `1`, based on your test inside the `if` block. So, `A != C`. This violates the transitivity principle.

I think, you should add some condition inside your `else` block, that performs check similar to how you do in `if` block.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is in your default case. Consider the set of nodes A, B, and C, where the IDs are `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. Consider further that your `childMap`, which contains the relative ordering information, has the following contents:

```
{ 'a' => 1, 'c' => 3 }
```

Now if you run your `compare` method on A and B, you return `0`, indicating that A and B are equivalent. Further, if you compare B and C, you still return `0`. However, if you compare A and C, then you return `-1`, indicating that A is smaller. This violates the transitivity property of [the `Comparator` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29):

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.

You can't treat "items which don't have an order assigned" as having the value "somewhere vaguely in the middle", since sorting algorithms don't know where to put them. If you want to stay with this approach, then in the case where the value is not present in the map, you need to assign a fixed value to be the ordering number; something like either `0` or `MIN_INT` is a  reasonable choice (but any choice needs to be documented in the Javadoc for `compare`!).

Comment: This answer also provides a solution, in addition to the explanation.