# Standard Deviation is not transitive?

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to implement a Comparator, considering that the objects going to be compared (`Word`) have two properties defined as `int`.

I want to get the standard deviation from these two values (may be more, but 2 now), and sort my list by which objects have the lowest one. But apparently, it is saying that my method is not transitive based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325256/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contr) (I presume, since I've got the same exception). But I cannot see how, here it will just compare the results of the standard deviation.

Am I confused with the math and did not consider a special case where points out that this method is not transitive or have I done something wrong?

*Sorting the list:*

```
for(Map.Entry<String,List<Word>> entry: list.entrySet()){
 Collections.sort(entry.getValue(), Collections.reverseOrder(new SimpleComparator()));
 ...
}
```

*Comparator Class:*

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SimpleComparator implements Comparator<Word> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Word word1, Word word2) {
        int b1,b2,f1,f2;
        double average1,average2, result1,result2;
        b1 = word1.getAttr1();
        b2 = word2.getAttr1();
        f1 = word1.getAttr2();
        f2 = word2.getAttr2();
        average1 = (b1-f1)/2;
        average2 = (b2-f2)/2;
        result1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b1-average1,2)+Math.pow(f1-average1,2))/2);
        result2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b2-average2,2)+Math.pow(f2-average2,2))/2);
        return (int)(result1 - result2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of rounding, your comparator is inconsistent with equals. I think you want to use (for example) ?: to get -1, 0, and 1 as the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Math.signum(result1 - result2)`, which will produce a -1 if the result is negative, 0 if the result is zero, and 1 if the result is positive. Make sure to keep the result as a double - The truncation that occurs when casting a double to an int would yield inaccurate results.

Instead, replace your return statement with:

```
return (int) Math.signum( result1 - result2 );
```

In this case, the result of `0.9 - 0.3` would be `0.6`, the signum of which would be `1`. However, if we were to cast the double `0.6` to an int, the result would be `0`, not `1`, indicating that they are equal. However, we know that this is not true. The reason for this is that when casting a numeric data type to one of lower precision, the value is not rounded - it simply loses precision, meaning that the values after the decimal point just fall off.

See the JavaDocs for [Comparator.comare(T, T)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,%20T))

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that maybe the ugly casting was the problem, but I didn't know about `Math.signum(a,b)`. However, if I should keep with double, how I am going to Override the Compare method?

Comment: So, trying to stay with double, using `return Double.compare(result1,result2);` would be ok, right?

Comment: You don't need to return a double, you just need to keep the precision of the resulting double when calculating the difference. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I know I don't need to return a double. That's why I couldn't use `Math.signum` with my Comparator. `Math.signum` returns a double, while `Double.compare` returns an int

Comment: Ah, I follow now. Yes, that would also work. It pretty much follows the same idea as Math.signum(...).

Answer (score 0):

Your `compare(x1,x2)` method violates the condition:

> the implementor must ensure that compare(x, y)==0 implies
>   that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z.

Here is a counter example to your method where `compare(w1,w2)=0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Word w1=new Word(2,5);
 Word w2=new Word(1,5);
 Word w3=new Word(2,4);

    System.out.println(Math.signum(getStandardDeviation(w1, w3))==Math.signum(getStandardDeviation(w2, w3)));
}

public static double getStandardDeviation(Word word1,Word word2)
{
    int b1,b2,f1,f2;
    double average1,average2, result1,result2;
    b1 = word1.getAttr1();
    b2 = word2.getAttr1();
    f1 = word1.getAttr2();
    f2 = word2.getAttr2();
    average1 = (b1-f1)/2;
    average2 = (b2-f2)/2;
    result1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b1-average1,2)+Math.pow(f1-average1,2))/2);
    result2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(b2-average2,2)+Math.pow(f2-average2,2))/2);
    return (int)(result1 - result2);
}
```

}