# Comparison method violates its general contract! while sorting

Tags: android, sorting, collections, comparator

I am getting below error while comparing two objects.

My code :

```
public static Comparator<HotelResult> HotelLowRatingComparator = new Comparator<HotelResult>() {

        public int compare(HotelResult s1, HotelResult s2) {

            Double StudentName1 = Double.valueOf(s1.getStarRating());
            Double StudentName2 =Double.valueOf(s2.getStarRating());

            int val=(int) Math.round(StudentName1 - StudentName2);

            Log.e("Comparator",String.valueOf(val));

            //ascending order
            return (int) Math.round(StudentName1 - StudentName2);


        }
    }
```

Error Log :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

> Process: com.tech.booking, PID: 27473
>                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
>                                                                                            at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:761)
>                                                                                            at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:497)
>                                                                                            at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:421)
>                                                                                            at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:210)
>                                                                                            at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1998)
>                                                                                            at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1900)
>                                                                                            at com.tech.booking.Hotel_Module.HotelSearchResult_Activity$4.onTabReselected(HotelSearchResult_Activity.java:692)
>                                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabReselected(TabLayout.java:1177)
>                                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1136)
>                                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
>                                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
>                                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1537)
>                                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325256/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contr

Comment: `System.out.println(Math.round(.5 - 1.0) == -Math.round(1.0 - .5));` Prints out `false`.