# Comparison method violates its general contract -- But I might want to?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable, compareto

I am trying to write a table sorter that will -always- sort null values to the bottom. So I have written a "wrapper" class that `implements Comparable`:

```
public class WrappedBigDecimal implements Comparable<WrappedBigDecimal> {
    public final BigDecimal value;

    public WrappedBigDecimal(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WrappedBigDecimal o) {
        if (value == null && (o == null || o.value == null)) { // both are null, thus equal
            return 0;
        } else if (value == null && (o != null && o.value != null)) { // value is null and compared value isn't
            return -1;
        } else if (value != null && (o == null || o.value == null)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return value.compareTo(o.value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }

}
```

You'll notice that the `compareTo` method only does null checks and then defers to the `compareTo` method of the wrapped value's class.

Then I wrote a `RowSorter` whose `Comparator` checks for the `SortOrder`

```
public class WrappedNumberSorter extends TableRowSorter<TableModel> {

    public WrappedNumberSorter(TableModel model) {
        super(model);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<?> getComparator(final int column) {
        Comparator c = new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                boolean ascending = getSortKeys().get(0).getSortOrder() == SortOrder.ASCENDING;

                if (o1 instanceof WrappedBigDecimal && ((WrappedBigDecimal)o1).value == null) {
                    if(ascending)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return -1;
                } else if (o2 instanceof WrappedBigDecimal && ((WrappedBigDecimal)o2).value == null) {
                    if(ascending)
                        return -1;
                    else
                        return 1;
                } else {
                    return ((Comparable<Object>) o1).compareTo(o2);
                }

            }
        };
        return c;
    }
}
```

But this throws an error (can't figure out why, can't reproduce -- read on):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Luckily, the error doesn't seem to affect anything because everything is working as intended.

I saw this question ([java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325256/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contr)) and I THINK my problem is that my comparison is not transitive. Although I'm not sure because if `A` == `B` and `B` == `C` then I think mine would also return `A` == `C` but I'm getting spun around trying to think about it.

Anyways, my questions are:

1. Is there a potential danger to *intentionally* making the row sorter sort nulls to the bottom in this way?
2. This SEEMS transitive to me. Am I, indeed, violating the transitive contract of `compareTo` here? Or is there another contract that it must adhere to and I'm unaware and that's what throws the error?

I wrote a method to test my row sorter and I am unable to reproduce the error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTable table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

    String[] headers = new String[] {"h1", "h2"};

    Object[][] data = new Object[10][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        data[i][0] = new WrappedBigDecimal(BigDecimal.TEN.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i % 3 == 0 ? (i*i*-1) : (i*i))));
    }

    data[7][0] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
    data[8][0] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
    data[9][0] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);

    for(int i = 10; i < 17; i++) {
        data[i-10][1] = new WrappedBigDecimal(BigDecimal.TEN.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i % 3 == 0 ? (i*i*-1) : (i*i))));
    }

    data[7][1] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
    data[8][1] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
    data[9][1] = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);

    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return BigDecimal.class;
        }
    });

    table.setRowSorter(new WrappedNumberSorter(table.getModel()));

    frame.add(jsp);
    frame.setSize(200,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Everything seems to be working smoothly.

What am I missing?

[image]

---

EDIT (7/11/18): Attempting to get rid of the `WrappedBigDecimal` solution and implement Matt McHenry's solution presents another problem. I simplified the `RowSorter` to this:

```
static class NullsLastSorter extends TableRowSorter<TableModel> {

    public NullsLastSorter(TableModel model) {
        super(model);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<?> getComparator(int column) {
        return Comparator.<Optional<BigDecimal>, Boolean>comparing(Optional::isPresent).reversed().thenComparing(o -> o.orElse(BigDecimal.ONE));
    }
}
```

And tested it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTable table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(table);

    String[] headers = new String[] {"h1", "h2"};

    Object[][] data = new Object[10][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        data[i][0] = BigDecimal.TEN.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i % 3 == 0 ? (i*i*-1) : (i*i)));
    }

    data[7][0] = null;
    data[8][0] = null;
    data[9][0] = null;

    for(int i = 10; i < 17; i++) {
        data[i-10][1] = BigDecimal.TEN.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i % 3 == 0 ? (i*i*-1) : (i*i)));
    }

    data[7][1] = null;
    data[8][1] = null;
    data[9][1] = null;



    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, headers) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return BigDecimal.class;
        }
    });

    table.setRowSorter(new NullsLastSorter(table.getModel()));

    frame.add(jsp);
    frame.setSize(200,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

And now when I try to sort I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.util.Optional
at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator2.compare(Collections.java:5178)
at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.compare(DefaultRowSorter.java:968)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.access$100(DefaultRowSorter.java:112)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(DefaultRowSorter.java:1376)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(DefaultRowSorter.java:1366)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sort(DefaultRowSorter.java:607)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(DefaultRowSorter.java:319)
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder(DefaultRowSorter.java:480)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(BasicTableHeaderUI.java:112)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Contract Violations

I see two pieces of the contract being violated:

- `WrappedBigDecimal.compareTo(null)`

The [javadoc for `Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) says that `compareTo(null)` must always throw a `NullPointerException`.  Your method does not obey this.

- `WrappedNumberSorter.getComparator()`'s handling of `WrappedBigDecimal(null)`

Consider this code:

```
WrappedBigDecimal x = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
WrappedBigDecimal y = new WrappedBigDecimal(null);
```

... along with this quote from the [javadoc for `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-):

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.

Using your code (assuming `ascending == true`), we have `compare(x, y) == 1`.  But `compare(y, x) == 1`.  Since `sgn(1) != -sgn(1)`, this is a violation of the contract of the `Comparator` interface.

### General Comments

Your overall goal of sorting nulls to the beginning or end is fine, in fact it's very common.  But you're missing a lot of opportunities to use library code.

#### Comparator helper methods

In Java, it's almost always easier to use the static helper methods in the `Comparator` class than to write your own `compare()` methods by hand. Indeed, there is a tailor-made one just for your use case: [`nullsLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)).

#### [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Instead of writing your own wrapper class to deal with `null` values for your `BigDecimal`, just use `Optional<BigDecimal>`.  This is exactly the sort of thing it's meant for.

#### Complete Solution

Since `Optional<T>` is a very general container class, it can't implement `Comparable<Optional<T>>` itself (there's no guarantee the type it's wrapping is `Comparable`).  But `Comparator`'s static helper methods make it easy to do ourselves.

First we sort by whether there is a value present or not, making sure that empty optionals go to the end rather than the beginning.

Then, when we have a pair of optionals whose "presence" is equivalent (either both present or both absent), we give a simple lambda to extract the value to compare.  `orElse()` is just what we need: if a value is present, get it and compare it; if a value is not present, provide a fallback.  (Remember, that last case only happens when *both* Optionals being compared are empty, so it doesn't matter *what* value we use as the fallback, it's always just compared to itself, giving the result we want: two empty optionals are equivalent.)

```
Comparator.<Optional<BigDecimal>,Boolean>comparing(Optional::isPresent)
          .reversed() //default ordering of booleans is false before true
          .thenComparing(o -> o.orElse(BigDecimal.ONE))
```

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that in order to accomplish what I want (have null values always at the bottom) then I must actually violate the `Comparator` contract?

Comment: No, you don't have to violate the contract.  Answer edited to demonstrate how to do this with library code much more succinctly.

Comment: Your complete solution didn't implement for me. Edited the question to show the error I'm getting.

Comment: Without seeing the full source code of `DefaultRowSorter`, my guess is that you're passing in "unwrapped" `BigDecimal` objects to the `compare()` method rather than "wrapped" `Optional<BigDecimal>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can, get rid of the wrapper class. And in the sorting method, check the values of each object and sort them accordingly. For example, you want all null instances to be put to the bottom. If one, or both, are null, treat them as values of -1

i.e)

```
@Override
public Comparator<?> getComparator(final int column) {
    return new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
                return -1;
            /**
             * Do the rest of your checks here
             */
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
}
```

Also, it looks like you are expecting "non-BigDecimal" objects to be compared in your BigDecimal comparable object.

A) If BigDecimal already implements Comparable, there is no need to re-implement the interface. Just override the existing method from the superclass.

B) WrappedBigDecimal is the Generic type, your code seems to be accepting other types that are not of this type, which may not be important here, but can definitely be causing you errors

Comment: "your code seems to be accepting other types that are not of this type" well, yes, because the real table has many columns that are not the same datatype but they will all be subject to the same `RowSorter`. So the rowsorter needs to account for them, too.

Comment: Indeed, the wrapper is so that the sorter only treats those particular wrapped types special. Every other datatype should be subject to the `compareTo` method of that type.