# Collections.sort() Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java

I am trying to sort arraylist based on comparing two strings using comparator ,but i end up with Comparison method violates its general contract error. How do i handle if null comparison occurs in the string.

Code

```java
Collections.sort(keyList, new DIMsComparator<DIM>(sortField));


public static class DIMsComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    String sortField = "";

    public DIMsComparator(String sortField) {
        this.sortField = sortField;
    }

    public int compare(T obj1, T obj2) {
        if (!(obj1 instanceof DIM) || !(obj2 instanceof DIM))
            return obj1 instanceof DIM ? -1 : obj2 instanceof DIM ? 1 : 0;
        DIM dim1 = (DIM) obj1;
        DIM dim2 = (DIM) obj2;
        // Changes for Grouping enhancement starts
        /*
         * if(dim1.getGroupName() != "" || dim2.getGroupName() != "") return -1;
         */
        // Changes for Grouping enhancement ends
        if (dim1.isTextLine())
            return 1;
        if (dim2.isTextLine())
            return -1;
        String[] mySortFields = Util.split(this.sortField, ",");
        for (int i = 0; i < mySortFields.length; i++) {
            if (mySortFields[i].equals(""))
                break;
            int value = compare(dim1, dim2, mySortFields[i]);
            if (value == 0)
                continue;
            else
                return value;
        }

        return dim1.dimSeqNo > dim2.dimSeqNo ? 1 : dim1.dimSeqNo < dim2.dimSeqNo ? -1 : 0;
    }
```

Error

```
[err] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
[err]   at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:788)
[err]   at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:525)
[err]   at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:452)
[err]   at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:256)
[err]   at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1856)
[err]   at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1471)
[err]   at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:186)
```

Comment: The class should be `DIMsComparator implements Comparator<DIM>`, your generics are wrong.

Comment: What does `int value = compare(dim1, dim2, mySortFields[i]);` do?

Comment: If you follow @Kayaman 's advice you won't need to check for types anymore!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11441813/4090157 the exception message means, that your comparison does not follow the contract for every `compare(..)` method, which is:

1. The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)
2. The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0))` implies `compare(x, z)>0`.
3. Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.

One error in your code is, that you only consider the first `dim` if it is a textline:

```
if (dim1.isTextLine())
    return 1;
if (dim2.isTextLine())
    return -1;
```

So if both `dim1` and `dim2` are textlines both comparisons `compare(dim1,dim2)` and `compare(dim2,dim1)` will return `1`, which violates the contract requirement 1.

And there may also be more inconsistancy in `compare(dim1, dim2, mySortFields[i])` which is impossible to tell, since you did not add source code for this function.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `[err] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

[Your solution probably is not transitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325256/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contr)

> If A == B and B == C, then A must be equal to C.

Regarding your question:

> How do i handle if null comparison occurs in the string.

[Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598770/check-whether-a-string-is-not-null-and-not-empty)

> if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())

You should also take a look at this line `int value = compare(dim1, dim2, mySortFields[i]);`
I'm not sure what it's supposed to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well the line I mentioned calls another `compare()` routine, obviously. The implied question is what does *that* do, and whether it complies with the specification. And why it wasn't posted in the question.