# Collections.sort - IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

Some of our users are getting this exception while sorting a list. The code that throws it is

```
Collections.sort(activeConverstions, new Comparator<Conversation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
            return (int)(o2.getTime()- o1.getTime()); // descending order
        }
    });
```

while getTime() is of type "long"

Comment: I may be wrong, but compare method should only return -1, 0 or 1

Comment: possible duplicate: [Java error: Comparison method violates its general contract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is probably casting a `long` to `int`, which may convert a large `long` number to a negative `int`.

For example, consider this snippet :

```
long first = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
long second = 0;
System.out.println((int) (first - second));
System.out.println((int) (second - first));
```

Output :

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

If you would pass to your `compare` method two `Conversation` instances - let's call them `x` and `y` - whose `getTime()` is equal to `first` and `second` in the above snippet respectively, both `compare(x,y)` and `compare(y,x)` would return a negative value, which violates the contract of that method.

Try :

```
Collections.sort(activeConverstions, new Comparator<Conversation>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
        return o2.getTime() > o1.getTime() ? 1 :  o2.getTime() < o1.getTime() ? -1 : 0;
    }
});
```

or, as assylias suggested :

```
Collections.sort(activeConverstions, new Comparator<Conversation>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
        return Long.compare(o2,getT‌​ime(), o1.getTime());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. will give it a try

Comment: Or more simply: `return Long.compare(o2,getTime(), o1.getTime());`

Comment: The only problem with Long.compare is it requires an min API level of 19

Comment: You could use Long.signum(o2.getTime() - o1.getTime()) if your jdk version does not have Long.compare(x1, x2)

Answer (score 2):

A best practice of implementing `compare` method is to only return -1, 0 or 1.

```
    Collections.sort(activeConverstions, new Comparator<Conversation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
            long result = o2.getTime()- o1.getTime();
            return result < 0 ? -1 : result > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

As @assylias mentioned it's even better to use already implemented compare methods:

```
    Collections.sort(activeConverstions, new Comparator<Conversation>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
            return Long.compare(o2,getT‌​‌​ime(), o1.getTime());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. the official docs says it returns "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second" but i think casting long to int might be a problem. will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: By 'should' I meant a best practice. A little misunderstanding. Edited.

Comment: It is not good practice to subtract numbers in a comparator because the subtraction may overflow (even if it's unlikely in this case). You should use `return Long.compare(o2,getT‌​ime(), o1.getTime());` instead or compare the times directly instead of calculating the difference.

Comment: @assylias Yup, +1, just editing and giving you credits

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
 Collections.sort(activeConverstions, 
    new Comparator<Conversation>()            {
    @Override
    public int compare(Conversation o1, Conversation o2) {
    if ((o2.getTime() > o1.getTime())
      return 1;
    else  if ((o2.getTime() < o1.getTime())
     return -1;
    else return 0;
    }
 });
```