# Java7 - Comparison method violates its general contract (TimSort.java)

Tags: java, sorting, java-7

Here is the stack trace I am getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
        at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
        at xxx.sortDisplayFields(OfferFieldLayout.java:521)
```

Here is the compare method:

```
  public int compare(Field pObject1, Field pObject2)
{
    int compare = 0;              

   //...
    if (compare == 0)
    {
        if (pObject1.hashCode() <= pObject2.hashCode())
        {
            compare = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            compare =  1;
        }
    }

    return compare;
}
```

I think this is due to the transitive property not being respected :
transitivity: if A > B and B > C then for any A, B and C: A > C. 
I am trying to come up with a counter example but I am failing here, any help appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java error: Comparison method violates its general contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: Can you show us the full comparison method?

Comment: Is this specific to Java 7?

Comment: The error started since the switch to Java8 since the change in the sort came with Java7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function can never return 0! This means that if everything in the objects are equal, including the hashcodes, then `pObject1.compare(pObject2)` will not equal `pObject2.compare(pObject1)`. The compare function must be symmetric. I also think you swapped around `-1` and `1` in that test, so your last check should be this:

```
if (compare == 0) {
    if (pObject1.hashCode() < pObject2.hashCode()) {
        compare = 1;
    } else if (pObject1.hashCode() > pObject2.hashCode()) {
        compare =  -1;
    }
}

return compare;
```

And by the way, your objects should implement the `Comparable` interface, and the method should be called `compareTo`.

And finally, comparing hashcodes is not a good idea to begin with. They can collide even though the objects are not equal. This means that your `compareTo` method can return `0` when the objects are not equal. This is also a breach of the `compareTo` contract.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting this part in the code. I think I should just use this
return Integer.compare(pObject1.hashCode(), pObject2.hashCode()) like the next answer mention. Or Just return 0 at that point since using hashCode seems like a bad practice..

Comment: Yes, I would rather just return 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (pObject1.hashCode() <= pObject2.hashCode())
{
   compare = -1;
} else {
   compare =  1;
}
```

This part is certainly not compatible with the `compareTo` contract, as if the hash codes are equal, the comparison is *not* equal.  Instead, you should use `return Integer.compare(pObject1.hashCode(), pObject2.hashCode())`, assuming you want to use hash codes for comparisons at all.  (It's not usually a good idea, as hash codes can just happen to collide.)