# TimSort violation

Tags: java, timsort

What's wrong with this comparator method?

I have read : 
[Java error: Comparison method violates its general contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

And understand that if c1 > c2, and c2 > c3, then c1 > c3. I believe this should hold true in the above.

getMaxCosine() returns value between 0..1, and 2nd sort is by the length of the text in the card, the longer the higher ranked.

```
public int compare(Card c1, Card c2) {
   if (getMaxCosine(c1) > getMaxCosine(c2)) {
       return -1;
   } else if (getMaxCosine(c1) == getMaxCosine(c2)) {
       return getMatchingText(c1).length() >= getMatchingText(c2).length() ? -1 : 1;
   } else {
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: If c1 and c2 have the same max cosine and the same matching text length, what *should* be the result? What is the *actual* result?

Comment: Note that your comparator could be simplified (and fixed) by simply using `Comparator.comparingDouble(this::getMaxCosine).thenComparingInt(c -> c.getMatchingText(c).length)`.

Comment: Hi @jb-nizet,
Thx - should I change the "else if" block to something like:

`else if (getMaxCosine(c1) == getMaxCosine(c2)) {
      if (getMatchingText(c1).length() > getMatchingText(c2).length()) return -1;
      else if (getMatchingText(c1).length() < getMatchingText(c2).length()) return 1;
      else return 0 
   }`

Comment: *In that case, the cards should be equal*: OK, so what should the compare() method return, according to the javadoc of Comparator, when two cards are equal? What does it actually return?

Comment: @AlexBenjamen Your question is unclear.  What exactly is happening, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese: 
I'm rarely getting an exception which is hard to reproduce: `Comparison method violates its general contract`.

Comment: Hint: `compare(card, card)` should return 0 for any value of `card`. It doesn't.

Comment: @AlexBenjamen I'm trying to let you find the solution by asking you a question that can be answered very easily by just reading the javadoc of Comparator.compare(), and the code of your method. But you don't want to answer it. Try answering it. Read the hint (which is basically the answer to my question) of Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is in your `if`-`else` block:

```
else if (getMaxCosine(c1) == getMaxCosine(c2)) {
       return getMatchingText(c1).length() >= getMatchingText(c2).length() ? -1  : 1;
}
```

If `getMatchingText(c1).length()` is equal to `getMatchingText(c2).length()` then you return `-1`.  This yields an "unstable" sort:  In other words, the order two objects with equal values will be reversed after sorting.  Moreover, you should return 0 for `Card`s that are equal under this comparator.  I suggest changing the `>=` comparison to just `>` in this `if`-`else` block:

```
else if (getMaxCosine(c1) == getMaxCosine(c2)) {
       if (getMatchingText(c1).length() == getMatchingText(c2).length()) return 0;
       return getMatchingText(c1).length() > getMatchingText(c2).length() ? -1  : 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd make this simpler: `return Integer.compare(getMatchingText(c2).length(), getMatchingText(c1).length());`

Comment: Thanks @ChocolateAndCheese for the explanation and solution! I think I was close to it, let me update my code and try it out

Comment: Thanks to @everyone who responded, this is really great support from the stack overflow community!