# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract Java 1.8

Tags: java

I am getting the Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` for the code below:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {

    if ((this.getStatus() == 1 && this.getSendBack() == 1)
            && (o.getStatus() == 1 && o.getSendBack() == 0))
        return 1; // greater than
    else if (this.getStatus() == 1 && o.getStatus() > 1)
        return 0; // equal to
    return -1; // less than
}
```

Additionally, this code is working for some of the conditions but it failing for some others. Moreover, I think this problem arises when I have some of the contradictory statements (please correct me if I am wrong), but I don't see having the same here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java error: Comparison method violates its general contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: `x.compareTo(x)` should be zero. If `x.compareTo(y) < 0` then `y.compareTo(x)` should be `> 0`. And if `x.compareTo(y) < 0` and `y.compareTo(z) < 0` then `x.compareTo(z)` should be `< 0`. Your comparison code doesn't look like it follows any of those rules.