# Comparator Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, comparator

How can I sort array according to the count of set bits? I'm getting an error whit below code:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> {
    if (Integer.bitCount(o1) <=  Integer.bitCount(o2))
        return 1;
    return -1;
});
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:781)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:518)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1441)
    at Compute.sortBySetBitCount(File.java:44)
    at GFG.main(File.java:23)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You **have to** return 0 when objects are "equals".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java error: Comparison method violates its general contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract). Tip: paste error messages you don’t understand immediately into your search engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never return `0`, even if the elements are equal. Using the `Comparator.comparing` methods is generally better for simple sorting methods.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount).reversed());
```