# Comparator in Arraylist

Tags: java, sorting

I have a List of my user defined class.

```
class Customer{
  Integer age;
  String name;
  //getter & setter
}


Collections.sort(customerList, new Comparator <Customer>() {        
  public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
    if(o1.getAge()!=null && o2.getAge() != null)
        return o1.getDistance().compareTo(o2.getDistance());
    else
      return 1;
  }
});
```

Now my **age** variable may have a **null** value or the **age of the customer**. All **null** values should be **appended** at the end and remaining values should sorted in **ascending or descending order(anything is ok)?**

But this code is **throwing an exception :**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Please tell me what to do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Full stack trace please...

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said to be consistent with equals if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for >every e1 and e2 in S.

Ref - [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Element set must be consistent. Inconsistent equals will behave straggly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not handling the cases correctly where only one of the customers has an age and the other has not.

Also, returning 1 in the else-situation seems to be incorrect. If there is no difference according to the age, then return 0 instead of 1.