# Comparison method violates its general contract, with long comparsion

Tags: comparison, long-integer, contract

```
Collections.sort(cells, new Comparator<MyCell>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyCell o1, MyCell o2) {
            if (o1.getX() <= o2.getX() && o1.getY() <= o2.getY()) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

    });
```

Here the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
```

I know there are many questions like this one but I don't get it why my comparision is wrong. getX() and getY() returns a long. So how can I fix this?

I already search for it, but didn't get an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/1930331) on the topic. A comparator must be transitive to work. Otherwise, you would not get the same results from different orderings of the initial items.

Comment: I already found this answer but I don't get it how to chang emy code so it would work?

Comment: It depends what X and Y do. You cannot change the code superficially to make this work. You will have to implement another comparison method. The problem is that if A has X,Y of 2,3 and B has 1,5, this method will tell me for A,B that A is greater than B, but for B,A, B is greater than A. There is no consistency! Consider handling the cases of X1>X2 but Y1<=Y2 or vice versa by returning a 0.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I just realised, that I have to test something else because this will not get the result I wanted.