# JGraph/JGraphX : Creating a very complex graph

Tags: java, jgraph, jgraphx

I'm currently working on a software allowing the creation of gamebooks, and I'm trying to add a graph view.  I create a graph where the vertices are the paragraphs and the edges the links between them.

The gamebook I created has over 100 paragraphs, and all of them are extremely interwoven.
First I tried to use JGraphX, but the result was a mush after application of the layout. Since help and examples for JGraphX are sparse I couldn't solve it, so I tried my luck with JGraph 5.13, because it had facade (couldn't find the JGraphX equivalent).

My problem is that the facade works pretty well for the first 87 edges I add to it. When I add just one more, I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at com.jgraph.layout.hierarchical.JGraphMedianHybridCrossingReduction.medianRank(Unknown Source)
at com.jgraph.layout.hierarchical.JGraphMedianHybridCrossingReduction.weightedMedian(Unknown Source)
at com.jgraph.layout.hierarchical.JGraphMedianHybridCrossingReduction.run(Unknown Source)
at com.jgraph.layout.hierarchical.JGraphHierarchicalLayout.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not sure what to do next. Is JGraph 5.13 not made for making such a chaotic graph? Is there some JGraphX facade equivalent I could use? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you paste the code where you are doing a comparison

Comment: This error indicates an incorrect `Comparator` implementation, did you write one? If yes, then please show that as well.

Comment: I wasn't doing a comparison myself, the exception happens when I do this code (and had 88 or more edges in the graph) :

    `hir.run(graphFacade);

    Map <Object, Object> nested = graphFacade.createNestedMap(true, true);

    graph.getGraphLayoutCache().edit(nested);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [comparator](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/src/com/mxgraph/layout/hierarchical/stage/mxMedianHybridCrossingReduction.java#L617) in 1 or 2 stages of the hierarchical layout that worked with Java 6, but [Java 7 started enforcing that they must be must be transitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract). We'll look into getting it fixed.

Comment: Alright thanks... I'll try to make do with the organic layout, for now it's pretty ugly but at least it doesn't make that exception.

Comment: The fix is very simple, I can push it to github on Monday, you can build it directly from there.

Comment: Wow that's some reactivity! I thought you meant something like "maybe someday" :D Thank you David!