# google script sort Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script and I get a messege saying my comparisson method violates its general contract.

```
  array1[i]=array1[i].sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    if(element_a[typeNum] == element_b[typeNum]){
      return element_b[3+types]-element_a[3+types];
    }
    return element_b[typeNum] - element_a[typeNum];
  });
```

typeNum and 3+types are both integers.
array[i] is a 2D array.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)