# Sort elements of scala list by set of conditions

Tags: scala, sorting, vector

I have a Scala list of objects which needs to be sorted based on two conditions. I have tried the sortBy method to sort the list of elements,mentioning the two feidls,but the sorting order is not as i expected.

```
TestObject(name:String,size:Int,length:Double)
val tesList = Vector[TestObject]()
```

I wanted to sort the list based on -

```
bigger SIZE & bigger LENGTH
```

I tried-

```
tesList.sortBy(p=>(p.size,p.length))
```

I want to sort elements of the list which has highest length and highest size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SortWith`.

You will need to define a sort function which will be used in `SortWith` to determine whether one object is bigger than the other. Based on the function, sorting will be done.

```
case class TestObject(name:String,size:Int,length:Double)
 val tesList = Vector[TestObject](TestObject("a",4,4), TestObject("a",4,5), TestObject("a",2,5))
//> tesList  : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[TestObject]
//|  = Vector(TestObject(a,4,4.0), TestObject(a,4,5.0), TestObject(a,2,5.0))
// f and s stands for first object and second object
 tesList.sortWith((f,s) => f.size > s.size && f.length > s.length)
 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[TestObject] = Vector(TestObject(a,4,4.0), TestObject(a,4,5.0), TestObject(a,2,5.0))
```

Comment: Hi,I tried your approach,but i end up with this error message-Comparison method violates its general contract!. I want to know,if we have a map that was converted to Seq or Vector then performed this sort,would it cause such error message? As i have a Map,that i convert to Seq to perform this sorting order.

Comment: No. As soon as it is converted to Seq or Vector, then Scala does not care where this Seq or Vector came from. I am not sure about  the error message, but you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract for better details.

Comment: I started testing out the same sort with other examples codes. Your sort gives "Vector(TestObject(a,4,4.0)" as the first element,but i want "TestObject(a,4,5.0)" as the first element,as its length is greater than the "TestObject(a,4,4.0)" and they both have same size.

Comment: What I gave is just an example. You can have any comparator function based on your exact needs. Instead of '(f,s) => f.size > s.size && f.length > s.length', you can have '(f,s) => if(f.size == s.size) f.length > s.length else f.size > s.size && f.length > s.length' which will give `TestObject(a,4,5.0), TestObject(a,4,4.0)` as the result.