# Java Collections sort: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparison

I know it has been asked and answered millions of times but still I am unable to figure out why I am receiving with the violation during sort. Here is my code:

```
Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject m1, MyObject m2) {
        // Actual energy comparison :-
        // THE higher the energy, the earlier in the list
        float delta = m1.getTotalEnergy() - m2.getTotalEnergy();

        if (delta > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (delta < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

and I receive this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:895)  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:512)  
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:453)  
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:250)  
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)  
        at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)  
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are any other threads changing the value of totalEnergy while the sort is running?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: @DavidXu nope single Thread is processing the  during this exception.

Comment: You could just use: return Float.compare(m1.getTotalEnergy(), m2.getTotalEnergy());

Comment: I would advise you check for **`null`** objects, before you start comparing properties.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I suspect there are NaN values. Do I have to use the following code then ? if (value < other.value)
  return -1;
else if (value >= other.value)
  return 1;
else
  return 0;

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl , without null check , would not I get "NullPointerException" instead of sort violation ?

Comment: I have copied this code and it does its job without any problems. Can you please show us the input data and type of the "sorted" collection? Like a minimum reproducible sample?

Comment: @R4J Thanks. the collection being sorted is ArrayList<MyObject> I cant give you a small data. The reason is I also dont get any errors during a small set. The problem occurs when I am trying to sort millions of records. I suspect some floats have NaN , do you think it could cause problem.

Comment: By the way, is it possible to print out which objects (2 or 3...)  are violating the "Contract" , how can I print them just before the StackTrace so have an idea to cope with the compareTo method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `getTotalEnergy()` return(s) `float`, you could use

```
return new Float(m1.getTotalEnergy()).compareTo(m2.getTotalEnergy());
```

Using [`Float.valueOf(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28float%29) is probably slightly more efficient, and hopefully this is easier to read.

```
Float f1 = Float.valueOf(m1.getTotalEnergy());
Float f2 = Float.valueOf(m2.getTotalEnergy());
return f1.compareTo(f2);
```

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I'm not. It's returning the result of [`Float.compareTo(Float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Float%29) with [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Yeah, but where in the code is the `return`? Hopefully not in the `compare()`.

Comment: Perhaps the code could be written to be more obvious.  This code sure looks like it returns a floating-point number to me.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004269/java-collections-sort-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract#comment44397154_28004269) makes more sense.

Comment: Prefer `return Float.valueOf(m1.getTotalEnergy()).compareTo(m2.getTotalEnergy());` to allow it to use the `Float` from cache rather than always creating a new one.

Comment: Ah, never mind.  I missed the `CompareTo`.  In other news, don't use "EDIT" in your answers.  Every Stack Overflow post has a comprehensive edit history that anyone can review.  The edit history for this answer is located [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28004369/revisions).

Comment: Just use the static `Float.compare()`.

Answer (score 1):

Without reference to `MyObject`. My guess is that the comparator is inconsistent with `MyObject.equal`.

That is, the contract you are violating is:

```
(comparator.compare(mo1, mo2) == 0) == mo1.equals(mo2)
```

Your comparator will compare objects with the same float value as being equal, where a more complex comparator would give an ordering, whilst the equals method would say the objects were not equal. Or you could have the reverse problem -- the equals method says the objects are equal and the compare method says they are different.

The following should work.

```
public int compare(MyObject m1, MyObject m2) {
    if (m1 == m2) return 0;
    if (m1 == null) return -1;
    if (m2 == null) return 1;
    if (m1.equals(m2)) return 0;

    int value = Float.compare(m1.getTotalEnergy(), m2.getTotalEnergy());
    if (value != 0) return value;

    // Warning, this line is not fool proof as unequal objects can have identical hash 
    // codes.
    return m1.hashCode() - m2.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a good guess since NaN does not causes Collections.sort to fail either.

Comment: @Dunes thanks , after trying Atuos' suggestion with Float.compare ( hoping it handles NaNs) I will try your suggestion. BR.

Comment: @math_law I have checked - NaN's are not the issue here. Can you show us MyObject.equals and MyObject.hashCode please?

Comment: @R4J I have not overridden these methods. Anything i can supply additionally ?

Comment: @R4J It could be a NaN. An object would compare differently to itself if its total energy was NaN, despite being equal to itself.

Comment: @Dunes I have copied the code and put some NaN's (0.0f / 0.0f) to the array - it still sorts :/

Comment: I checked the specs of `Float.compare` It compares `NaN` as equal to itself and greater than all other floats. It does however, compare `0f` as greater than `-0f`. So you may want to test that corner case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will make the change:

```
public int compare(Object m1, Object m2) {
    // Actual energy comparison :-
    // THE higher the energy, the earlier in the list
    float delta = ((MyObject)m1).getTotalEnergy() - ((MyObject)m2).getTotalEnergy();
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested with float, NaN, and null values. All cases are handled correctly. I created a `hashCode()` and `equals()` method to the `MyObject` class.

Result: `[null, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, NaN]`

### SortObjectFloatProperty

```
package q28004269;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SortObjectFloatProperty {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<MyObject> sorted;

        sorted = create(1f, 4f, 6f, null, 8f, 5f, Float.NaN, 3f, 2f, 7f, 0f, 9f);

        Collections.sort(sorted, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(MyObject m1, MyObject m2) {
                if (m1 == m2) return 0;
                if (m1 == null) return -1;
                if (m2 == null) return 1;
                if (m1.equals(m2)) return 0;
                int value = Float.compare(m1.getTotalEnergy(), m2.getTotalEnergy());
                if (value != 0) return value;
                return m1.hashCode() - m2.hashCode();
            }
        });

        System.out.println(sorted);
    }

    public static MyObject create(float totalEnergy) {
        return new MyObject(totalEnergy);
    }

    public static List<MyObject> create(Object ...values) {
        List<MyObject> objs = new ArrayList<SortObjectFloatProperty.MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] instanceof Float) {
                objs.add(create((float) values[i]));
            } else {
                objs.add(null);
            }
        }
        return objs;
    }
}
```

### MyObject

```
package q28004269;

public static class MyObject {
    private float totalEnergy;

    public float getTotalEnergy() {
        return totalEnergy;
    }

    public void setTotalEnergy(float totalEnergy) {
        this.totalEnergy = totalEnergy;
    }

    public MyObject() {
        this(0.0f);
    }

    public MyObject(float totalEnergy) {
        this.totalEnergy = totalEnergy;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Float.floatToIntBits(totalEnergy);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
        return !(Float.floatToIntBits(totalEnergy) != Float.floatToIntBits(other.totalEnergy));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Float.toString(totalEnergy);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just used implemented the compareTo method proposed here and it worked. Not sure if my object is Null or has some NaN value inside the totalEnergy method. While I would prefer single line of solutions (Stuart's or Elliot's) the only solution that worked in this thread is this. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

There was some discussion of `NaN` values in the comments. This is important, because `NaN` violates our typical expectations of comparisons of floating point numbers. For example, `Double.NaN > 0.0` and `Double.NaN < 1.0` are both false!

This may cause the sort to throw the exception as you encountered. Even if the exception isn't thrown, it may cause the list to end up sorted in the wrong order. Therefore, your sort comparator **must** deal with `NaN` values. Fortunately, the library's built-in comparisons such as `Double.compare()` do this for you. This has the same semantics as `Double.compareTo()`, except that boxed `Double` values aren't necessary. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) for details. Briefly, `NaN` values are considered greater than all other values (including `+Inf`), and negative zero is less than positive zero.

To use `Double.compare()` in a `Comparator` for `sort`, do this:

```
Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    public int compare(MyObject m1, MyObject m2) {
        return Double.compare(m1.getTotalEnergy(), m2.getTotalEnergy());
    }
});
```

If you're using Java 8, you could do this:

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getTotalEnergy));
```

To handle nulls, wrap the comparator with `nullsFirst` or `nullsLast`:

```
data.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getTotalEnergy)));
```

Comment: @math_law Still the same IAE? Try instrumenting the comparator, i.e. print out (or log) the inputs and result of each call, and then look at the last entry prior to getting the exception.

Comment: @math_law If your input does have nulls, try wrapping the comparator with `Comparator.nullFirst` or `Comparator.nullsLast` (Java 8 only).

Comment: @math_law Also, does `getTotalEnergy` always return the same value for any given instance of `MyObject`?