# Sorting locations: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, sorting, comparator

I have a class `LocationComparator`, which looks like this:

```
public class LocationComparator implements Comparator<MyLocation> {

    double mLatitude, mLongitude;

    public LocationComparator(double baseLat, double baseLon){
        mLatitude = baseLat;
        mLongitude = baseLon;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(MyLocation o, MyLocation o2) {
        float[] result1 = new float[3];
        android.location.Location.distanceBetween(mLatitude, mLongitude, o.latitude, o.longitude, result1);
        Float distance1 = result1[0];           

        float[] result2 = new float[3];
        android.location.Location.distanceBetween(mLatitude, mLongitude, o2.latitude, o2.longitude, result2);
        Float distance2 = result2[0];           

        return distance1.compareTo(distance2);
    }    
}
```

Next, I have `List<MyLocation> locations` and I want to sort it. I use this code:

```
Collections.sort(locations, new LocationComparator(baseLat, baseLon));
```

where `baseLat` and `baseLon` is latitude and longitude of current position. Sometimes, the code throws an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`.

I know, that this exception is thrown in case that `compare` method does not satisfy the condition of transitivity. I found some information here: [Comparison method violates its general contract!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract). I understand why the exception is thrown in referenced issue, but still I don't know why exception is thrown in my code.

Could you help me, please? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

List of `MyLocation` is used for adapter for `ListView`. In case, that there is a new GPS location, data in `ListView` are sorted. The code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    super.onLocationChanged(location);
    sortAdapter(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mIsSortedByLocation = true;   
    }
}
```

And `sortAdapter(LatLng latLng)` method is here:

```
private void sortAdapter(LatLng latLng) {
    if (mAdapter == null || latLng == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<MyLocation> list = Arrays.asList(mAdapter.getItems());
    Collections.sort(locations, new LocationComparator(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
    mAdapter.setItems(mMyLocations = (MyLocation[]) list.toArray());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The data comes from server. First, data are stored into the database, and then, there is a my `ContentProvider` and `Loader`. In `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor`), the data from `cursor` are stored into the `array` and this `array` is used for creating an `adapter`, which extends from `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: Could it be that your `MyLocation` is mutable and modified from another thread while sorting is running?

Comment: If you use this solution, what happens? `return Float.compare(result1[0], result2[0]);`

Comment: I think that there is not big difference, because `Float.compare(float float1, float float2)` is called from `compareTo(Float object)`. Am I right or there is some difference?

Comment: You are right. I was suspecting that maybe your `compareTo` call is causing the issue "somehow" so a static reference might resolve this? (Crazy, right?) :-)

Comment: I think I understand the cause of your problem. You have a collection of `MyLocation` which some of `MyLocation` results in having the same comparator results. This can be attributed to the fact that you're always using the first element of the `result` array to determine the equality of `MyLocation`. A better solution to `compareTo` needs to be implemented here.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi first element of `result` contains the distance. That's (very ugly) Android API.

Comment: I still do not know where is the problem. The first element of `result` contains the distance. I do not see the problem in this...

Comment: @PSglass please post more code: your `MyLocation` class, how do you acquire it and what happens after sorting

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing details of your code, I would assume that your problem comes from concurrency.

```
List<MyLocation> list = Arrays.asList(mAdapter.getItems());
Collections.sort(locations, new LocationComparator(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
```

It's either typo in your example, or `locations` reference is indeed populated outside of the method scope. So, I assume you're loading it from the server. Or it might very well be that you're modifying contents of `Adapter` from the background thread.

Avoid changing data from background thread which is used by the main thread. So, you must either synchronize on your collection before using it or just pass the result from background thead to main thread `Handler`:

```
List<MyLocation> locations;

void myBackgroundTask() {
    List<MyLocation> result = getLocationsFromServer();
    runOnUiThread(() -> { locations = result }); // lambda or Runnable
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. You're right, the problem might be a concurrency, but... Data comes from server, but adapter is created in `onLoadFinished`. This method is called from UI thread. You can check my next update.

Comment: @PSglass could you please paste the whole Activity/Fragment class?