# Comparison method violates its general contract! Java7 Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:408)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
```

Can someone explain why my comparator below sometimes throws the above exception.

Note: The id field in myObject is of type long.

```
Collections.sort(objectList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final myObject myobject1, final MyObject myObject2) {

        return (int)(myObject1.getId() - myObject2.getId());

    }
});
```

---

**Solution:**

Based on the answer from @amit

```
return (int)(Long.compare(myObject1.getId(), myObject2.getId());
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/4807777

Comment: myObject should have an upper case M - Java code conventions are not optional and classes always start with a capital letter.

Comment: @LionC apologies that was a typo. That's not what's causing the problem.

Comment: @Eran no, there is no possibility of nulls in the Collection

Comment: @LionC Code conventions are always optional; it is just not advisable to deviate from such a common convention.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel **Everything** is optional. But there is a lot of things that people should never ever think of as optional. This is such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might encounter an integer overflow if the ID is relatively high integers in absolute values, which will cause `VERY_HIGH_INT - VERY_LOW_INT` to be a negative number. This is obviously wrong, and is breaking the contract of the comparator.

Use [`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) (or similarly [`Long.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,%20long)), [`Double.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double))...) rather than substracting numbers to avoid it.

---

**EDIT:**

Specifically here, the problem is still integer overflow, when casting a long value where its 32 LSbs are in range [2^31,2^32) from `long` to `int`, which causes it to be erroneously negative. [Demo in ideone](http://ideone.com/GgqEdp).

Solution is the same. Use `Long.compare()`

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue as long as only positive integer ids are used. And if you need more ids, I would consider using unsigned comparison, so that id `0` is always first.

Comment: The id is based on System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @user5222688 See edit. The problem is still integer overflow.

Comment: @kajacx It is still an issue when you case the long to int. see edit.

Comment: @amit you are spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**`Java 7`** has changed the default sort algorithm from `MergeSort` to `TimSort` in the `java.util.Arrays.sort` method.

The sorting algorithm used by `java.util.Arrays.sort` and (`indirectly`) by `java.util.Collections.sort` has been replaced. The new sort implementation may throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it detects a Comparable that violates the Comparable contract.

For backward compatibility and to restore the behavior from Java version 6, add new system property- [java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.doc.user.lnx.60/diag/appendixes/cmdline/Djavautilarraysuselegacymergesort.html).

Refer the following link for details -

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#source

Comment: While informative, it does not answer the question. The OP is familiar with the contract, and doesn't really cares which sorting algorithm is involved. He cares why the contract in his comparator is broken, and this does not answer it.