# Java: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, collections, comparator, mediastore

I got the exception from above which I know was discussed often here on SO. Anyways, the others don't tell me what's wrong with my code. These `StyleAlbum` are just Music albums. `getAdded()` returns the time when their last song was added to Android's MediaStore in milliseconds as `int`.
This happens only on some devices!

Code:

```
public static List<StyleAlbum> sortAdded() {
    List<StyleAlbum> mAlbums = new ArrayList<>();
    mAlbums.addAll(Library.getAlbums());
    Collections.sort(mAlbums, new Comparator<StyleAlbum>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(StyleAlbum lhs, StyleAlbum rhs) {
            if (lhs.getAdded() > rhs.getAdded()) {
                return -1;
            } else return 1;
        }
    });
    return mAlbums;
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the full exception, including stack trace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Answer (score 1):

Your comparator does not account for two items being equal, ie it never returns zero. You should use something like

```
return Integer.compare(lhs.getAdded(), rhs.getAdded());
```

otherwise the result is at least inconsistent, and depending on the algorithm it may even be completely wrong. In this case, *Tim sort* (the algorithm used in the JDK) is smarter enough to tell you that there's an error.

*Note: I compared integers with `Integer.compare` instead of a subtraction (thanks Louis Wasserman) to avoid overflow errors*

Comment: Generally speaking, you should use `Integer.compare` instead of just subtracting, which can lead to overflow errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should return 0 in the compare method if both values are the same. Especially, a comparison from an object to itself should give 0.