# Getting error: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, collections, java-7, comparator

I have tried many possible solution given on the net like to set System property and to convert in double but still getting same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:835)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:453)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:392)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:191)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
```

Here is my code:

```
        System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");
        Collections.sort(docs, new Comparator<FeedDocument>() {
            public int compare(FeedDocument o1, FeedDocument o2) {

                int year1 = 0;
                int year2 = 0;
                int returnResult = 0;
                if (o1.containsKey(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR)
                        && o2.containsKey(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR)
                        && o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) != null
                        && (o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String)
                        && o2.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) != null
                        && (o2.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String)) {

                    String firstyear = (String) o1.get((FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR));
                    String secondyear = (String) o2.get((FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR));

                    if (firstyear.equals(secondyear)) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (firstyear != null && !firstyear.isEmpty() && secondyear != null
                            && !secondyear.isEmpty()) {

                        year1 = Integer.parseInt(firstyear.trim());

                        year2 = Integer.parseInt(secondyear.trim());

                        // int result = year2 - year1;
                        // if (result > 0) {
                        // returnResult = 1;
                        // } else if (result < 0) {
                        // returnResult = -1;
                        // }
                        return Double.compare(year2, year1);
                    }

                } else {
                    returnResult = 0;
                }
                return returnResult;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: Just FYI `instanceof` returns `false` if its left argument is null, no need for another check.

Comment: Yeah, you can combine `o1.containsKey(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) && o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) != null && o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String` into simply `o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String`. 

You also have additional unnecessary checks down the road: `firstyear != null` and `secondyear != null`. These just clutter the code and make it harder to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edward Peters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005784/4905782) is correct in diagnosing your problem, as your `compare` method doesn't produce consistent (transitive) results.

The best way to resolve this is something like the following in your `compare` method:

```
if (o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String) {
    if (o2.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String) {
        // Perform the comparison here like you are
    } else {
        /*
         * This could also be 1, the key is to have it consistent
         * so the final sorted list clearly separates the FeedDocuments
         * with a String PUBLICATION_YEAR and those without one.
         */
        return -1;
    }
} else if (o2.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) instanceof String) {
    /*
     * In this case, o1 doesn't have a String PUBLICATION_YEAR and o2
     * does, so this needs to be the opposite of the return value
     * 6 lines up to be consistent.
     */
     return 1;
} else {
     /*
      * Consider all FeedDocuments without a String PUBLICATION_YEAR
      * to be equivalent, otherwise you could do some other comparison
      * on them here if you wanted.
      */
     return 0;
}
```

The key is, if you only care about a subset of the list being sorted (the `FeedDocument`s with a `String` publication year, then you need to first separate them from the rest of the list that you don't care about being sorted (by returning either 1 or -1 when one of the `FeedDocument`s has a `String` publication year and the other doesn't). Then, you are free to sort the desired subset without inconsistent results.

Comment: I have not understood  /*
     * In this case, o1 doesn't have a String PUBLICATION_YEAR and o2
     * does, so this needs to be the opposite of the return value
     * 6 lines up to be consistent.
     */

Comment: @TanuGarg at the `return -1` line, we have determined that `o1` has a publication year, and that `o2` does not. So, `return -1` says that `o1` (and all `FeedDocument`s with a publication year) should come before those that don't have a publication year. At the `return 1` line, we have determined that `o1` doesn't have a publication year, but `o2` does, which is the opposite scenario of the first. So, saying `return 1` puts `o1` (and all `FeedDocument`s without a publication year) after those that have a publication year, which matches what happened on the `return -1` line.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for explanation also error has been resolved.

Comment: @TanuGarg no problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure I know what's happening here...

Suppse:

```
o1.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) != null
o2.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) == null
o3.get(FeedConstants.PUBLICATION_YEAR) != null
```

Then:

```
compare (o1, o2); //returns 0
compare (o2, o3); //returns 0
compare (o1, o3); //returns not 0
```

So you're claiming `o1 == o2 == o3` but `o1 != o3`

Comment: @TanuGarg You just have to make it so a single null value doesn't return equality. The standard I generally use is "If they're both null they're equal, if one is null it's automatically lesser, if neither are null compare normally."