# What is the correct way to handle IOException in a comparator?

Tags: java

I'm using a comparator to sort files by modified date. Those files are to be processed for contained data and deleted after. I have to make sure the files are in sequential order before processing them. Below is what I have so far.

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator<Path> {  
    @Override
    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
        try {
            return Files.getLastModifiedTime(o1).compareTo(Files.getLastModifiedTime(o2));
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            //write to error log
            //***
        }
    }
}
```

*** This is where I'm stuck. I have to return an int because compare requires it but I don't want to return zero and have false equivalency when it fails.

I tried restructuring the code but then if getLastModifiedTime() fails, o1Modified and o2Modified will be null.

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator<Path> {  
    @Override
    public int compare(Path o1, Path o2) {
        FileTime o1Modified = null;
        FileTime o2Modified = null;        
        try {
            o1Modified = Files.getLastModifiedTime(o1);
            o2Modified = Files.getLastModifiedTime(o2);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            //write to error log

        }

        return o1Modified.compareTo(o2Modified);

    }
}
```

Is there any standard way to handle situations like this?

Comment: If you receive an `IOException`, the implication is that something is wrong with your path(s). If one (or both) of your paths point to a file that doesn't exist, would it not make sense to say they're unequal? You can sort that how you wish (by returning either -1 or 1, depending on the exact case). Another way to put it is that all invalid Paths are equally invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way to tackle this particular situation is by calling `Files.getLastModifiedTime()` on each path exactly once, storing the results and then using the stored results during the sorting.

This has several benefits:

1. It cleanly solves the `IOException` problem.
2. It doesn't repeatedly and unnecessarily perform the same costly I/O operations on the same files.
3. It ensures consistent ordering even if the last modification time of a file changes midway through the sort (see, for example, ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract) for how this could subtly break your code).

Comment: Good answer that solves the problem at the root cause instead of a band-aid.

Answer (score 2):

Throw a runtime exception wrapping the IOException:

```
    try {
        return Files.getLastModifiedTime(o1).compareTo(Files.getLastModifiedTime(o2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException("impossible to get last modified dates, so can't compare", e)
    }
```

Note however that the modified time could change during the sort, which would make your comparator incorrect: it wouldn't respect its contract anymore. So a better approach would be to iterate through your paths first, and wrap them into some `TimedPath` object which would store the last modification time, and then sort those TimedPath objects.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a TimedPath object. NPE's answer solves my problem and your suggestion of creating a time aware object improves the solution.