# Java: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I am looking at some legacy code and I found a section that is causing me to get a “Comparison method violates its general contract!” error. I understand that this error is the result of the code not being transitive, but I don't fully understand how to fix it correctly.

Here is the code responsible for the error.

```
private void sortHistories(List<History> histories) {
        Collections.sort(histories, new Comparator<History>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(History o1, History o2) {

                return o1 == o2 ? 0
                        : o1 == null ? -1
                        : o2 == null ? 1
                        : o1.getFamilyMembers().equals(o2.getFamilyMembers()) ? 0 //getFamilyMembers() returns a string
                        : o1.getFamilyMembers() == null ? -1
                        : o2.getFamilyMembers() == null ? 1
                        : o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o2.getFamilyMembers()) != 0 ?
                                o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o2.getFamilyMembers())
                        : o1.getDisease().equals(o2.getDisease()) ? 0 //getDisease() also returns a string
                        : o1.getDisease() == null ? -1
                        : o2.getDisease() == null ? 1
                        : o1.getDisease().compareTo(o2.getDisease());
            }
        });
    }
```

Originally, the code was using `==` rather than `equals()` when comparing the strings `getDisease()` and `getFamilyMembers()`. I thought making the change from `==` to `equals()` would fix the problem, but that is not the case.

Comment: you have to check o1.getDisease() equals to null or not before comparing os.getDisease() whether equals to o2.getDisease()

Comment: The `==` was an optimization. Two lines below, `o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o2.getFamilyMembers()) != 0` does the real work. So `==1 *was* correct (and redundant).

Comment: @HaifengZhang I have tried that, in addition to moving another null check, but I am still getting the error. I have posted my updated code above.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann So I should get ride of `o1.getFamilyMembers().equals(o2.getFamilyMembers()) ? 0` and everything else will be fine?

Comment: I do not see anything like `o1.getFamilyMembers().equals(o2.getFamilyMembers())` but I do see `o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o2.getFamilyMembers())` is this correct? Because this will always return `0`.

Comment: i tried your code and could not reproduce your exception

Comment: @YoungHobbit Yes you are right! It seems to be working now!

Comment: @HaifengZhang It seems to be working now with both your suggestion and the other persons! Thank you!

Comment: Please do add your solution as answer for the completeness of the post. :)

Comment: @YoungHobbit done

Comment: Adding the solution into Question is not a right thing, you should post it as Answer. Thanks.:)

Comment: @YoungHobbit Ok. I just didn't want it to seem that I was stealing your guys' credit. I have posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The solution, thanks to HaifengZhang and YoungHobbit, is:

```
public int compare(History o1, History o2) {
                return o1 == o2 ? 0
                        : o1 == null ? -1
                        : o2 == null ? 1
                        : o1.getFamilyMembers() == null ? -1
                        : o2.getFamilyMembers() == null ? 1
                        : o1.getFamilyMembers() == o2.getFamilyMembers() ? 0
                        : o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o1.getFamilyMembers()) != 0 ?
                                o2.getFamilyMembers().compareTo(o1.getFamilyMembers())
                        : o1.getDisease() == null ? -1
                        : o2.getDisease() == null ? 1
                        : o1.getDisease() == o2.getDisease() ? 0
                        : o1.getDisease().compareTo(o2.getDisease());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation carefully.Throwing this exception is a new Java7 feature.

More details here :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/3080158

The old behavior can be configured with a new system property: java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#source

[image]

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

[image]

Comment: Agree that this may get rid of the exception, but it won't fix the sort order, will it?

Comment: Yes, to fix the sort order compactor should follow the contract,i.e for lt -1 , gt 1, and equals 0 , with transitivity.

Comment: That's clear, so, how does the OP do that given the code that was posted?

Comment: I didn't tried to solve the problem particularly, but if you go through the threads and docs ,the rule of thumb will be `check equality (a==b ? 0), then null(a or b is null -1,1),then compare or repeat for child` . If you check null first for example a==null? -1 then it might happen that b is also null , for which you should actually return 0.