# Why does this compareTo() method lead to a contract violation while sorting?

Tags: java

I have a list of filenames and want to compare these in the following order:

- all names ending with ".rar" should come **before** files with ".r01", ".r02", ...
- all names ending with ".par2" should come **after** files with with any other suffix

So I am using the following `compareTo` method for one of my Java classes:

```
public class DownloadFile implements Comparable<DownloadFile>
{
    // custom code ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DownloadFile other)
    {
        if(other == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Object other must not be null");

        // special cases -- .rar vs .par2 etc.
        String thisStr = filename.toLowerCase();
        String oStr = other.getFilename().toLowerCase();
        if(thisStr.endsWith(".rar") && oStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$"))
            return -1;
        if(thisStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$") && oStr.endsWith(".rar"))
            return 1;
        if(!thisStr.endsWith(".par2") && oStr.endsWith(".par2"))
            return -1;
        if(thisStr.endsWith(".par2") && !oStr.endsWith(".par2"))
            return 1;

        // normal comparison based on filename strings
        return thisStr.compareTo(oStr);
    }
}
```

However, on some data this leads to the following execption:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I tried to understand what I am missing here, but I can't find the issue.
Can you spot where I am violating the contract?

PS: If I comment out the second two `if`s, then the exeception is still thrown. So the problem lies with the first two `if`s.

Comment: First of all, do you know one of the most probable cause of this error? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/1743880

Comment: And all files with ".r02" endings have to come before those with  ".par" at the end?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz You mean before those with ".par2" at the end? Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Furthermore, your comparator is not declared correctly. `compareTo` should take an argument of type `DownloadFile`. You should not use `instanceof`! (Even if it does make the `null` check redundant.) Throwing an exception for `null` seems harsh, but it's the author's (your) choice. Why didn't the compiler warn you that you weren't actually overriding `compareTo`? Did you declare the `Comparator` as a raw type? Don't.

Comment: Why are you ignoring case in the comparison? That could cause different files to seem equal in name.

Comment: @LewBloch When I use `DownloadFile` as argument type, **then** the compiler is warning me that I would not override the method. So why (how?) would I use `DownloadFile` as argument then?

Comment: You declared the type wrong. You only showed part of your code, and the error is in the part you didn't show. I ask again, did you declare the `Comparator` as a raw type?

Comment: @LewBloch My class is implementing the `Comparable` interface, as shown in the updated code above. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Not directly, because you should have been able to say, "Why, yes, I did declare it as a raw type!" That is why your override is backwards. `Comparator` is a generic type, and should be used as `implements Comparator<DownloadFile>`. Do not use raw types. Do bother to look up what "raw type" means, especially if someone is asking you about it, which is a rather broad hint that it might just possibly be relevant to you.

Comment: A small point: according to [the `Comparable` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-), the wrong type should throw `ClassCastException`, not `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @LewBloch You're absolutely right, thanks for the feedback. I have changed the class to `public class DownloadFile implements Comparable<DownloadFile>` and the method to `public int compareTo(DownloadFile other)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not transitive.
Linear ordering of elements is not possible.

**Proof by counterexample.**

Say you have got 3 `DownloadFile`s (`c`, `b`, `a`) with names in lowercase:

```
c.par2
b.notpar2
a.par2
```

To simplify I will use `<` for linear ordering and names in lowercase.

`c.par2 < b.notpar2` and `b.notpar2 < a.par2`, but it is not true that `c.par2 < a.par2`.
This relation is not [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation).

In logic... it would be like:

`cRb` and `bRa`, but it is not true that `cRa`.

All you have to do is to answer how to order your files linearly...
I would go for something like this:

```
if(aMethodOnThis < aMethodOnOther) {
    return -1; //or 1
}
if(aCompletelyDifferentCriterium) {
    //...
}
return 0; //or return thisFileName.compareTo(otherFileName);
```

The `return 0` at the end is quite important, because it returned for indistinguishable files.

In that case:

```
public class DownloadFile implements Comparable<DownloadFile>{

    String filename;

    DownloadFile(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return this.filename;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getFilename();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DownloadFile downloadFile) {
        String thisStr = this.filename.toLowerCase();
        String oStr = downloadFile.getFilename().toLowerCase();
        if(thisStr.endsWith(".rar")) {
            if(!oStr.endsWith(".rar"))
                return -1;
        }
        if(oStr.endsWith(".rar")) {
            if(!thisStr.endsWith(".rar"))
                return 1;
        }
        if(thisStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$")) {
            if(!oStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$"))
                return -1;
        }
        if(oStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$")) {
            if(!thisStr.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$"))
                return 1;
        }
        if(thisStr.endsWith(".par2")) {
            if(!oStr.endsWith(".par2"))
                return -1;
        }
        if(oStr.endsWith(".par2")) {
            if(!thisStr.endsWith(".par2"))
                return 1;
        }
        return thisStr.compareTo(oStr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DownloadFile> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("a.rar"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("b.rar"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("a.r01"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("b.r01"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("a.r10"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("b.r10"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("a.par2"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("b.par2"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("a.other"));
        fileList.add(new DownloadFile("b.other"));
        Collections.shuffle(fileList);
        Collections.sort(fileList);
        System.out.println(fileList);
    }
}
```

To make it shorter `Predicate<String>` from Java 8 comes in handy ;)

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DownloadFile downloadFile) {
    String thisStr = this.filename.toLowerCase();
    String oStr = downloadFile.getFilename().toLowerCase();
    List<Predicate<String>> conditionList = new ArrayList<>();
    conditionList.add(s -> s.endsWith(".rar"));
    conditionList.add(s -> s.matches(".*\\.r[0-9]{2,}$"));
    conditionList.add(s -> s.endsWith(".par2"));
    for(Predicate<String> condition : conditionList) {
        int orderForCondition =
                conditionHelper(thisStr, oStr, condition);
        if(orderForCondition != 0)
            return orderForCondition;
    }
    return thisStr.compareTo(oStr);
}

private int conditionHelper(String firstStr, String secondStr,
                            Predicate<String> condition) {
    if(condition.test(firstStr))
        if(!condition.test(secondStr))
            return -1;
    if(condition.test(secondStr))
        if(!condition.test(firstStr))
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the `if(aMethodOnThis < aMethodOnOther)` you recommend, am I not doing that with my `if` already?

Comment: Yes, you do it. But your conditions are not so different. In your case it boils down to the decision... you want files with `.par2` endings to come first before other files or not? I think two if conditions out of 4 at the end are redundant.

Comment: I have added an explanation of the desired ordering logic to my original question.

Comment: I understand what you mean with "not transitive", but I don't understand **why** this is the case. Following your example my code would result in `b.notpar2 < a.par2` and `b.notpar2 < c.par2` and `a.par2 < c.par2` ... or wouldn't it?

Comment: @Matthias, it does not matter. If your code behaves like that it says nothing about its transitiveness. A relation R is transitive, iff for all elements from the given set: `aRb` and `bRc` implies `aRc`. In your example about `bRa` and `bRc`... transitiveness says nothing on the order of `a` and `c`.