# Sorting map by size of value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, collections, compare

I just have a simple compare method to sort a `Map` by the size of value which is a set.

```
public List<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> orderByDescStringSetSize(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map){
    Set<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> set = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>>(set);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>>>(){
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> o1, Map.Entry<String, HashSet<String>> o2){

            Integer o1Vals = o1.getValue().size();
            Integer o2Vals = o2.getValue().size();

            //descending
            if(o2Vals > o1Vals)
                return 1;
            else if(o2Vals==o1Vals)
                return 0;
            else
                return -1;

        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract`! Why so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

Comment: Add an example of the Map that causes the exception to be thrown.

Comment: Yes on the duplication. I'd suggest a `return o2Vals - o1Vals;` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of you! I am sorry that I made a duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `o2Vals==o1Vals` is not doing what you expect.

You are working with `Integer` **Objects** - please use `equals`!!

This may not be the only issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn't think about that

Comment: Or better, use `int` here, as there is no reason to use `Integer` when `size()` returns an `int`. Or simplify the entire method to `return Integer.compare(o1.getValue().size(), o2.getValue().size());`

Answer (score 0):

Using the same approach that you did I will modify:

- The size of the `HashSets` is an `int`, use it for comparison rather than `Integer`.
- No need to add `if else if else` if you are returning the value. Moreover, you can just return the values substracted: `return o2Vals - o1Vals`.
- You are using `Entry` in some points and `Map.Entry`, are you sure you have the correct imports? In any case, I suggest you to use one or the other always to ensure the types are the same.

This said, the solution should look like:

```
public List<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> orderByDescStringSetSize2(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map) {
    Set<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> set = map.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, HashSet<String>> o1, Entry<String, HashSet<String>> o2) {
        int o1Vals = o1.getValue().size();
        int o2Vals = o2.getValue().size();

        // Descending
        return o2Vals - o1Vals;
    }
    });
    return list;
}
```

However, if you are using Java 8 you can take advantage of the `Stream` interface and do it more compact without defining a `Comparator`:

```
public List<Entry<String, HashSet<String>>> orderByDescStringSetSize(HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream() // Create stream
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(entry -> -((Entry<String, HashSet<String>>) entry).getValue().size())) // Sort descending
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collect
}
```