# IllegalArgumentException in ArrayList.sort()-method

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I got following exception and I don't quite unterstand why:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its
>   general contract!
>
> at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777) at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514) at
>   java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441) at
>   java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245) at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) at
>   java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)

I wrote following JUnit test to verify the behavior:

```
@Test
public void testComparator() {
    List<Boolean> item = new ArrayList<>();

    item.add(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        item.add(false);
    }

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Sorting");
        Collections.shuffle(item);

        item.sort((lineItem1, lineItem2) -> {
            if (lineItem1 && lineItem2) {
                return 0;
            } else if (!lineItem1) {
                return 1; 
            } else if (!lineItem2 ) {
                return -1;
            } 

            return 0;
        });
    }
}
```

If I swap the return 1 and return -1, it suddenly works without exception. 
But why? This should only change the sorting order and not break the whole comparator.

What am I missing?

Comment: Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract) already?

Comment: Does your code violate this rule? `The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)` from [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-)

Comment: You are violating the contract because you currently return 1 when lineItem1 is false regardless of what value lineItem2 has.

But if both are false you need to return 0.

Comment: @doc: I would say, no it doesn't violate it. compare(true, false) = -1, compare(false, true) = 1 and sgn(-1) == sgn(1)

Comment: Have you tried compare(false, false)?

Comment: @C.Koenig compare(A=false, B=false) returns 1 but compare(B=false, A=false) also returns 1. So which one would be sorted higher in that case: A or B? Both are bigger than the other after all.

Comment: By the way, "doc" is not a person ;-)

Comment: If I may be allowed to plug my talk on this subject.... Part 1: https://youtu.be/Enwbh6wpnYs ... Part 2: https://youtu.be/bvnmbRo7a1Y

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You comparator violates the contract, as when both arguments are `false`, it will return `1` due to the statement `if (!lineItem1) { return 1;  }…`.

Generally, there is no guaranty that TimSort will spot incorrect comparators, it doesn’t actively try to find contract violations, it just detects some cases as a side effect of the algorithm.

What you actually want to to is

```
item.sort((lineItem1, lineItem2) -> {
    if (lineItem1.equals(lineItem2)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (!lineItem1) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

though you could achieve the same just using

```
item.sort((lineItem1, lineItem2) -> lineItem1^lineItem2? lineItem1? -1: 1: 0);
```

or even simpler

```
item.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: So its basically luck, that no exception is thrown, when I exchange the ordering?

Comment: @C.Koenig exactly. Before the introduction of the TimSort algorithm, such problems were never reported, you could even have the luck to see the desired result order, or rather, bad luck as you didn’t noticed the still existing problem in the code…