# Exception while sorting a list of objects based on date property(String type)

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of Objects based on dates (In String). The dates are in string and the objects have date property value assigned "-" if there is no date with it.
I am doing the below code snippet to sort it however at one point it is giving me " **Comparison method violates its general contract**" exception. I am not able to figure out where the contract is breaking and how.

I looked into other threads but could not get much help.

Any inputs what could I be doing wrong?

```
Collections.sort(listOfObjects, new Comparator<ObjectType>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(ObjectType objectOne, ObjectType objectTwo) {
                if(sortType.equalsIgnoreCase("asc")){
                        if(objectOne.getSomeDate().equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
                            return 1;
                        if(objectTwo.getDeliveryQueueResponseDTO().getSomeDate().equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
                            return -1;
                        sort = objectOne.getSomeDate().compareToIgnoreCase(objectTwo.getSomeDate());
                    }
                    else
                        sort = objectTwo.getSomeDate().compareToIgnoreCase(objectOne.getSomeDate());
                }

return sort;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement correctly the comparison between to `"-"` (empty dates).

If you don't you get that `a="-"` and `b="-"` you have that `compare(a,b)==1` and `compare(b,a)==1` so `a>b` and `b>a` which don't make sense.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means your comparator is not transitive.  For more details, look at this question:

["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)