# Comparison method violates its general contract, sorting by different properties

Tags: java, android, comparator

Need to sort some items based on a time stamp/ current hour and/or the name property of the item's person object in alphabetical order. How would I correct the IllegalArgumentException which is thrown in some cases?

```
    public static final Comparator<Item> sortByTimeAndName = new Comparator<Item>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Item lhs, Item rhs) {
                if(lhs.getDate() != null && rhs.getDate != null){
                    if (lhs.getDate().getTime() < rhs.getDate().getTime()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (lhs.getDate().getTime() == rhs.getDate().getTime()) {
                        if (lhs.getHour() < rhs.getHour()) {
                            return -1;
                        } else if (lhs.getHour() == rhs.getHour()) {
                            if(lhs.getPerson().getName().compareTo(rhs.getPerson().getName()) == 0){
                              // if two persons have same name, sort by person id
                                if (lhs.getPerson().getID() < rhs.getPerson().getID()){
                                    return -1;
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                return lhs.getPatient().getName().compareTo(rhs.getPatient().getName());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (lhs.getHour() < rhs.getHour()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (lhs.getHour() == rhs.getHour()) {
                        if(lhs.getPerson().getName().compareTo(rhs.getPerson().getName()) == 0){
                            if (lhs.getPerson().getID() < rhs.getPerson().getID()){
                                return -1;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            return lhs.getPerson().getName().compareTo(rhs.getPerson().getName());
                        }
                    }
                }

                return 1;
            }
        };
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:761)
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:497)
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:421)
       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:210)
       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1998)
       at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1900)
....
```

Comment: full stack trace of `IllegalArgumentException`, please post it.

Comment: See also [“Comparison method violates its general contract!”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assume there are 3 objects of type `Item` such as: 
for `a`: assume `getDate() == null`
for `b`: assume `getDate() != null`
So the comperartor's result is
 
assume `if (lhs.getHour() < rhs.getHour())` is `true` then `a < b` 
also 
for `b`: assume `getDate() != null`
for `c`: assume `getDate() != null`
So the comperartor's result is
 
assume `if (lhs.getDate().getTime() < rhs.getDate().getTime())` is `true` then `b < c` 
also 
for `a`: assume `getDate() == null`
for `c`: assume `getDate() != null`
So the comperartor's result is
 
assume `if (lhs.getHour() > rhs.getHour())` is `true` then `a > c` 
(because of the final `return 1`)

As you can see there is a contradiction:
`a < b` and `b < c` but `a > c`
I believe that cases like this violate the comparison method's general contract.