# compareTo comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I want to compare two "Recipients" by the dateLastContact, and if it's the same, by the address. So this is my code:

```
public class RecipientComparator implements Comparator<Recipient> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Recipient o1, Recipient o2) {
        if (o1.isDateLastContactNull() || o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
            if (o1.isDateLastContactNull() && o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
                return o1.getAddress().compareTo(o2.getAddress());
            } else if (o1.isDateLastContactNull()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (o1.getDateLastContact().equals(o2.getDateLastContact())) {
                return o1.getAddress().compareTo(o2.getAddress());
            } else
                return o1.getDateLastContact().compareTo(o2.getDateLastContact());
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I always have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:899)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:516)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:439)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)
    at managers.RecipientManager.getAllRecipientFromAPI(RecipientManager.java:28)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

I have tried a lot of things but now, I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

The recipient class:

```
package recipientPackage;

import paramPackage.Param;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Recipient {
    private String recipientID;
    private String address;
    private String status;
    private int contactCount;
    private Date dateLastContact;
    Param param;
    private String[] attributes = {"recipientID", "address", "status", "contactCount", "dateLastContact"};

    Recipient(String[] recipientBrut, boolean isComeFromMailing) {
        if (isComeFromMailing) {
            createRecipientMailing(recipientBrut);
        } else {
            createRecipientSurvey(recipientBrut);
        }
    }

    public void createRecipientMailing(String[] recipientBrut) {
        this.setRecipientID(recipientBrut[0].substring(recipientBrut[0].indexOf(':') + 1).replaceAll("\"", ""));
        this.setAddress(recipientBrut[1].substring(recipientBrut[1].indexOf(':') + 1).replaceAll("\"", ""));
        this.setStatus(recipientBrut[3].substring(recipientBrut[3].indexOf(':') + 1).replaceAll("\"", ""));

        try {
            this.setDateLastContactForMailing(recipientBrut[5].substring(recipientBrut[5].indexOf(':') + 1).replaceAll("\"", ""));
            this.setContactCount(Integer.parseInt(recipientBrut[4].substring(recipientBrut[4].indexOf(':') + 1).replaceAll("\"", "")));
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            this.setDateLastContactForMailing(null);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createRecipientSurvey(String[] recipientBrut) {
        setAddress(recipientBrut[0]);
        setStatus(recipientBrut[1]);
        setDateLastContactForSurvey(recipientBrut[2]);
        param.setParam_point_collecte(recipientBrut[5]);
        param.setParam_langue(recipientBrut[6]);
        param.setParam_semaine(recipientBrut[7]);
        param.setParam_periode(recipientBrut[8]);
        param.setParam_envoi(recipientBrut[9]);
        param.setParam_type_visiteur(recipientBrut[10]);
        param.setParam_saison(recipientBrut[11]);
    }

    private void setDateLastContactForMailing(String dateLastContact) {
        if (dateLastContact != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                this.dateLastContact = formatter.parse(dateLastContact);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else
            this.dateLastContact = null;

    }

    private void setDateLastContactForSurvey(String dateLastContact) {
        if (!dateLastContact.equals("")) {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            try {
                this.dateLastContact = formatter.parse(dateLastContact);
            } catch (ParseException ignored) {
            }
        } else
            this.dateLastContact = null;

    }
    public Boolean isDateLastContactNull() {
        return (dateLastContact == null);
    }

    public String getRecipientID() {
        return recipientID;
    }

    public void setRecipientID(String recipientID) {
        this.recipientID = recipientID;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getContactCount() {
        return contactCount;
    }

    public void setContactCount(int contactCount) {
        this.contactCount = contactCount;
    }

    public Date getDateLastContact() {
        return dateLastContact;
    }

    public void setDateLastContact(Date dateLastContact) {
        this.dateLastContact = dateLastContact;
    }

    public String[] getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(String[] attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract

Comment: @Lorelorelore I have seen this... doesn't help me.

Comment: Can you add Recipient class? Maybe it is easier to help you with that.

Comment: @Lorelorelore I have edited my question with the recipient ! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are violating the contract of the compare method, your relationship is not transitive. *"The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`"*

Consider this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Recipient r1; // with isDateLastContactNull() == true;
    Recipient r2; // with isDateLastContactNull() == false;
    RecipientComparator rc = new RecipientComparator();

    System.out.println(rc.compare(r1, r2)); // -1
    System.out.println(rc.compare(r2, r1)); // -1
    // both print -1 which is not transitive.
}
```

The reason is because of this code:

```
if (o1.isDateLastContactNull() && o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    // if both null, return comparison of addresses
    return o1.getAddress().compareTo(o2.getAddress());
} else if (o1.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    // if first null, return -1
    return -1;
} else if (o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    // if second null, also return -1 ?
    return -1; // should probably be 1 instead
}
```

You should probably return `1` for the second condition.

---

The contract is as defined here:

**`int compare(T o1, T o2):`**

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. In the foregoing description, the notation `sgn(expression)` designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to return one of `-1`, `0`, or `1` according to whether the value of expression is negative, zero or positive.
>
> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that `compare(x, y)` must throw an exception if and only if `compare(y, x)` throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive:  `((compare(x, y) > 0) && (compare(y, z) > 0))` implies `compare(x, z) > 0`.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y) == 0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z)) == sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.
>
> It is generally the case, but not strictly required that `(compare(x, y) == 0) == (x.equals(y))`. Generally speaking, any comparator that violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this comparator imposes orderings that are inconsistent with equals."

Comment: Yes, this is the thing I have already understand,  but I don't really understand where I did this violation :/

Comment: I've edited my answer. The issue is that your compare function is not transitive if you always return `-1` for any input having `isDateLastContactNull() == true`

Answer (score 1):

One obvious reason is this:

```
} else if (o1.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    return -1;
} else if (o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    return -1;
}
```

either `o1.isDateLastContactNull()` is `true` **xor** `o2.isDateLastContactNull()` is `true` 
then `o1 < o2`.  
Did you mean:

```
} else if (o1.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    return -1;
} else if (o2.isDateLastContactNull()) {
    return 1;
}
```