# Understand comparison method when sorting a collection

Tags: java, sorting, comparison, comparator

I have the following piece of code to sort a collection of Items that have a label property:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<ListItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ListItem lhs, ListItem rhs) {
                Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "lhs.getLabel(): " + lhs.getLabel() + " | rhs.getLabel(): " + rhs.getLabel());
                if (lhs.getLabel() == null || rhs.getLabel() == null) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return lhs.getLabel().compareTo(rhs.getLabel());
            }
        });
```

I have some crash reports with the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
       at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
       at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1498)
       at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1470)
       at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:201)
       at uk.co.aquanetix.activities.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:59)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I understand that this is related to the fact that the comparator method is not transitive, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8327575/1204249).

My problem is that I am not able to reproduce it. It only happens in some specific situation that I can't figure out.

As you can see, I am sending the label values to Crashlytics, so these are the values that were sent when the crash happened.

```
0 | 1545921010869 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 14:49:22 | rhs.getLabel(): 13:21:22
1 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 13:25:41 | rhs.getLabel(): 14:49:22
2 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 13:25:41 | rhs.getLabel(): 14:49:22
3 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 13:25:41 | rhs.getLabel(): 13:21:22
4 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 14:53:26 | rhs.getLabel(): 13:25:41
5 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel(): 14:53:26 | rhs.getLabel(): 14:49:22
6 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel():  | rhs.getLabel(): 14:49:22
7 | 1545921010870 | D/MyActivity lhs.getLabel():  | rhs.getLabel(): 13:25:41
```

I built a list with those values (plus some items with empty strings) but no luck in reproducing it in my device/emulators.

My questions are:

- What could be the reason for not being able to reproduce using the same values?
- Should the code be better without the `if` condition?

Comment: Your comparison function returns `0` when *either* of the objects is `null`. You probably want to decide whether `null` objects go at the beginning of the sorted-set or at the end and be consistent about it.

Comment: Comparison that you have will not be able to sort collection of labels `'a', 'b', null`, because `'a' < 'b'`, `'a' == null` and `'b' == null`, which makes it simultaneously `'a' < 'b'` and `'a' == 'b'` (because, `'a' == null == 'b'`), which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted, this comparator isn't transitive. Consider three `ListItem`s `a`, `b` and `c` with the labels `"a"`, `"b"` and `null`, respectively. Using this comparator, `compare(a, c)` and `compareTo(b, c)` are both `0` since `c.getLabel()` is `null`, but `compare(a, b)` clearly isn't, thus breaking the rule of tansitivity.

To address this issue you can arbitrarily decide that `ListItem`s with `null` labels will always go last (or first, for argument's sake. Just replace the `1`s in the below code with `-1`s and vise-versa):

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<ListItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ListItem lhs, ListItem rhs) {
        if (lhs.getLabel() == null) {
            if (rhs.getLabel() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        if (rhs.getLabel() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return lhs.getLabel().compareTo(rhs.getLabel());
    }
});
```

Note that if you're using Java 8 you can save a lot of this boilerplate code:

```
myList.sort(Comparator.comparing
            (ListItem::getLabel, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Comment: In the second case with ``nullLast`` you will still get ``NullPointerException``

Comment: @SchiduLuca oops, that was sloppy on my behalf. Edited and fixed.