# Postgres data to osm-pbf creation failed using osmosis snapshot schema

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osm.pbf

I have imported pbf to postgres using osmosis snapshot schema

now wanted to create pbf from that schema, using following command

> osmosis --read-pgsql host=localhost database=osmosisv1 user=postgres password=postgres postgresSchema=contry_snapshot validateSchemaVersion=no --dataset-dump --write-pbf C:\usr\share\osm.pbf

but getting following exception

```
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-pgsql failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.PostgreSqlDatasetReader.run(PostgreSqlDatasetReader.java:59)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:781)
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:518)
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
        at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.sort.common.FileBasedSort.flushAddBuffer(FileBasedSort.java:89)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.sort.common.FileBasedSort.add(FileBasedSort.java:118)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.database.SortingStoreRowMapperListener.process(SortingStoreRowMapperListener.java:38)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.database.SortingStoreRowMapperListener.process(SortingStoreRowMapperListener.java:17)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.common.RowMapperRowCallbackListener.processRow(RowMapperRowCallbackListener.java:46)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor.extractData(JdbcTemplate.java:1578)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:440)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:457)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.impl.EntityDao.getFeaturelessEntity(EntityDao.java:208)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.impl.EntityDao.iterate(EntityDao.java:253)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.impl.EntityDao.iterate(EntityDao.java:279)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.impl.PostgreSqlDatasetContext.iterate(PostgreSqlDatasetContext.java:214)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.dataset.v0_6.DumpDataset.process(DumpDataset.java:46)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.pgsnapshot.v0_6.PostgreSqlDatasetReader.run(PostgreSqlDatasetReader.java:57)
        ... 1 more

Jun 18, 2021 10:05:17 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForCompletion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see the exception it clearly mentions following error

> Comparison method violates its general contract!

This is due to Comparator is not transitive, There is ID Comparator and the ids in database are randomly generated, so randomly generated ids making problem to this comparator

["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

> **conclusion :** Randomly generated ids have to be in incremented way, should not contain negative values