# Comparison Method violates its general contract in Java 7

Tags: java

I am getting a "Comparison Method violates its general contract" after compiling some Java code in Java 7, and then running it.

I have read [Comparison method violates its general contract! Java 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849539/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-java-7-only) and realize that there is something wrong with my code that was ignored in previous versions of Java. However I cannot work out what is wrong with my code. The Collections.sort() generates the error.

My code is:

```
   public Comparator sortBySmoothDays() {
    Comparator c = new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
            Date date0 = ((PosObject)arg0).getDate();
            Date date1 = ((PosObject)arg1).getDate();

            double d1 = MyUtils.calcSmoothDays(date0, new Date());
            double d2 = MyUtils.calcSmoothDays(date1, new Date());
            if (d1 >= d2) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return -1;
            }   
        }
    };
    return c;
}


Comparator c = ComparatorUtils.getInstance().sortBySmoothDays();
Collections.sort(posList, c);
```

Can anyone help?  Thank you!

Comment: JFI: Throwing this exception is a new Java7 feature. The old behavior can be configured with a new system property: java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417446/450812

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A comparator must return 0 if the values are equal. In your current implementation, you return 1 if they are equal. The easiest way to compare your `double` values correctly is to call [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-):

```
double d1 = MyUtils.calcSmoothDays(date0, new Date());
double d2 = MyUtils.calcSmoothDays(date1, new Date());

return Double.compare(d1, d2);
```

Comment: It returns 1, not -1.

Comment: @Boann Because 3.5 years ago, I was stupid :). Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 19):

With  your comparator, every object compares greater than itself: `compare(x,x)` always returns one.

This violates the following [requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29):

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

The above requirement implies that `compare(x,x)` must return zero.

I would recommend reading the [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) and making sure your implementation fulfils it.

In particular, if `date0.equals(date1)`, the comparator probably ought to return zero right away, without doing any floating-point conversions and comparisons.

Comment: More generally, no two objects can ever be equal to each other using this method.  There is no code path that yields the 0 (or equal) result.

Answer (score 3):

Isnt the issue that if two objects compare equal i.e. calcSmoothDays returns the same value, then you could have a situation where compare(object1,object2) == 1, and compare (object2,object1) == 1 also?

So it implies that object1 > object 2 and object2 > object 1...