# java exception: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

I have already checked previous posts on this topic -- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325256/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contr). In spite of that, I couldn't figure out how the contract violation can happen in my code given below.

```
public class ScoreComparator 
implements Comparator<Map.Entry<?, Double>> {

public int compare(Map.Entry<?, Double> o1, 
        Map.Entry<?, Double> o2) {
    return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
}   
}
```

The way I make use of this is as follows:

```
List<Entry<String, Double>> entryList = 
        new ArrayList<Entry<String, Double>>(
                iterTypeScoreMap.get(keyToSort).entrySet());
Collections.sort(entryList, new ScoreComparator());
```

and iterTypeScoreMap is declared as follows

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Double>> iterTypeScoreMap;
```

The map (iterTypeScoreMap) can change during the sort which is why I made a copy of the list and then call sort on it.

Since I am using the built-in compareTo method of Double, shouldn't that take care of the contracts? Another thing that makes this hard to debug is that this exception doesn't happen always; only happens during some of the runs. What could be the bug here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use this comparator to directly sort a `SortedMap`? Or you use it on separate collection (eg. `List<Map.Entry<?, Double>>`?

Comment: Are the values in your map potentially changing during the sort?

Comment: Other related questions: ["Comparison method violates its general contract!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327514/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract) as well as [Comparison Method violates its general contract in Java 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486605/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-in-java-7)

Comment: @Jack, good point. Included that in the edit to the question.

Comment: @Sbodd, please check the edit. It does change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that your sort order is changing during the sort operation, due to the entry values (scores) being changed concurrently.

It doesn't help to make a copy of the map's `entrySet()` when the entries themselves are being concurrently modified. You'd have to deep copy the collection, in other words copy all of the `Entry` objects as well, in order to prevent the error. As it stands, the list you're sorting has references to the same Entry objects as the original map.

Comment: yes, I think that was the problem. Thank you. I created AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry based on the map entries and inserted them into the list to be sorted. That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `a.compareTo(b)==0` should imply `a.equals(b)`.

However, if your keys are different but values are the same, then the two would have `a.compareTo(b)==0` but `a.equals(b)` would be `false`.

Comment: No, this is not implied. Just strongly suggested.

Comment: I think that whatever sorting algorithm the OP is using might assume (although incorrectly) that it is implied. I know `TreeSet` does, removing elements that are not equal but where `a.compare(b)==0`.

Comment: From `TreeMap` documentation: _The behavior of a sorted map is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface._