# "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!" error for a Collections.sort()

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to sort a bunch of numbers and have the following code:

```
//sort possible targets based on distance
                Collections.sort(allPossibleTargets, new Comparator<NPD2>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(NPD2 o1, NPD2 o2) {
                        if (o1 == null && o2 == null)
                            return 0;
                        if (o1 == null && o2 != null)
                            return 1;
                        if (o1 != null && o2 == null)
                            return -1;
                        return o1.getNpd().getDistance() < o2.getNpd().getDistance() ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                });
```

However, I get the above exception. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're Comparator doesn't return 0 if both objects are equal.

See this post: [Comparison Method violates its general contract in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486605/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-in-java-7)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Try to explain the issue in the answer.