# Using Java build option useLegacyMergeSort=true with android gradle

Tags: java, android, build, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to set the following option:

```
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

with gradle build for android. This is to circumvent [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575224/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-timsort-and-gridlayout)

My question is how do I add this option in 'Android Studio'? I tried to add it in the Compiler->VM options, but to no avail.

I also tried setting it in the command line (JAVA_OPTS) and building with the gradle command, but that didn't work either.

I'm using Java 1.8 and Gradle 2.2.1

Comment: any success? I also need this

Comment: there's a comment in the android source: `// Android-changed: LegacyMergeSort is no longer supported` in Arrays.java