# Random error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, android, file, sorting, collections

**What I Have**

```
enum FileItemComparator implements Comparator<FileItem> {

    //Using ENUM
    NAME_SORT {
        public int compare(FileItem o1, FileItem o2) {

            int result = 0;
            if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {

                String n1 = o1.getFileName();
                String n2 = o2.getFileName();

                if (n1 != null && n2 != null)
                    result = n1.compareTo(n2);
            }

            return result;
        }
    },
    DATE_SORT {
        public int compare(FileItem o1, FileItem o2) {

            int result = 0;
            if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {

                String d1 = o1.getFileDate();
                String d2 = o2.getFileDate();

                if (d1 != null && d2 != null) {

                    Long l1 = Long.valueOf(d1);
                    Long l2 = Long.valueOf(d2);

                    if (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
                        result = l1.compareTo(l2);
                    }
                }

            }

            return result;
        }
    },
    SIZE_SORT {
        public int compare(FileItem o1, FileItem o2) {

            int result = 0;
            if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {

                File f1 = o1.getItem();
                File f2 = o2.getItem();

                if (f1 != null && f2 != null) {

                    result = Long.valueOf(f1.length()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(f2.length()));
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<FileItem> descending(final Comparator<FileItem> other) {

        return new Comparator<FileItem>() {
            public int compare(FileItem o1, FileItem o2) {
                return -1 * other.compare(o1, o2);
            }
        };
    }

    public static Comparator<FileItem> getComparator(final FileItemComparator... multipleOptions) {
        return new Comparator<FileItem>() {
            public int compare(FileItem o1, FileItem o2) {
                for (FileItemComparator option : multipleOptions) {
                    int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I have this code which is used to sort the files based on name, date or size.

But I get this error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:864)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:481)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:406)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:210)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2010)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1883)
```

Some of my users get this error and I see it in the crash reports. But I can not reproduce this error myself in any way.

Can anyone please help me in finding the problem. I have really seemed to have spent a lot of hours in this but couldn't find anything. Please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A similar question is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract

Comment: @Gero Yes, I saw this question before and can't seem to fix my problem. It would be great if you can help me solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20236925/13116) and searching for TimSort (as stated on your stacktrace), you can reach [this bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575224/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-timsort-and-gridlayout) that may be your case.

As [madth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13575810/13116) suggests, one workaround could be adding to your code:
`System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");`

Comment: Using legacy merge sort should be the last option I think. In my code I have just used compareTo method and not my own logic. I dont know where I am doing wrong.