# Set system properties in standalone-full.xml in wildfly 8.2

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have added system-properties tag in standalone-full.xml, but its not working in standalone mode. However, if I add the same tag in domain.xml it's working for domain mode.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">

    <extensions>
    ....
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>
</server>
```

According to [this article on jBoss General configuration concepts](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/General+configuration+concepts)

> System property values can be set in a number of places in domain.xml, host.xml and standalone.xml.

Then what about standalone-full.xml?

I don't want to set it through command line and not even in java code.

Comment: It might be related to the classload order ... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26829874/453389

Comment: Note that this question is in relation to a property used by the Java Platform itself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In standalone it's probably too late to set it in the configuration files. You'll need to add it to the `standalone.conf` or `standalone.conf.bat` in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable. A global property like that needs to be set before anything else attempts to use `java.util.Arrays`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have started the Wildfly server with standalone-full.xml instead of standalone.xml(the default) than this should be reflected in the start of the server:

```
standalone.sh -b <hostIP> -c standalone-full.xml -Dorg...
```

Then this will have effect on first start.

If you change something in this config file, you will need to reload Wildfly(configuration) from jboss cli:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] :reload
```

Answer (score -1):

For Wildfly 10 it's working nontheless. I was able to read the property for an instance started with the standalone-full.xml containing some properties.

The manual must be outdated then I guess? Because even Wildfly itself inserts a new property in the standalone-full.xml when using the Wildfly admin webinterface: http://localhost:9990 > Configuration > System Properties (Wildfly will add the property of course to the xml config which was used to start the instance). That's enough proof for me.