# maven-artifact ComparableVersion doesn't work well with java colllections sort algorithm timsort: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, maven, timsort

ComparableVersion offered by maven-artifact is used in my project to sort artifact by its version. For example, these versions is offered(should spilt by //).

```
0.0.1576817712//0.0.3//0.0.4//0.0.4.//0.0.4.1//0.0.4.2//0.0.4.3//0.0.4.4//0.0.4.5//0.0.5//0.0.5.1//0.0.5.2//0.0.5.3//0.0.5.4//0.0.6//0.0.7//0.0.8//0.1.0//0.1.2//0.1.2.1//0.1.2.2//0.1.2.3//0.1.2.4//0.1.2.5//0.1.2.6//0.1.2.7//0.1.2.8//0.1.3//0.1.3.1//0.1.3.2//0.1.3.3//0.1.4//0.1.4.1//0.1.4.2//0.1.4.3//0.1.4.4//0.1.4.5//0.1.4.6//0.1.4.7//0.1.4.8//0.1.4.9//0.1.5//0.1.7//0.1.7.1//0.1.7.2//0.1.7.3//0.1.7.4//0.1.7.5//0.1.7.6//0.1.7.7//0.1.8//0.1.9//0.1.9.1//0.1.9.11//0.1.9.12//0.1.9.13//0.1.9.2//0.1.9.3//0.1.9.8//0.1.9.9//0.1.9.9.1//1.0.0.1//1.0.0.2//1.0.0.3//1.0.0.3.1//1.0.0.4//1.0.0.5//0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.11-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576066498-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576066912-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576209616-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576677646-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576722159-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576732580-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576737990-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576757185-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576812388-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576817712-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576821661-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576821977-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576825998-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577182101-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577266235-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577267400-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577268933-SNAPSHOT//0.0.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.3-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.11151113-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.2.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.20180829-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.20181115-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.4.181113-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.6-SNAPSHOT//0.0.7-SNAPSHOT//0.0.8-SNAPSHOT//0.0.9-SNAPSHOT//0.0.91576063257-SNAPSHOT//0.0.91576066026-SNAPSHOT//0.1.0-SNAPSHOT//0.1.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.9-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.l-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.y-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.yl-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.yy-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5-push-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.l-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.testpush-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.y-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.yl-SNAPSHOT//0.1.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.6.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.8-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.15-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.16-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.9.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.9.3-SNAPSHOT//0.2.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.2-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.3-lv-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.3-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.4-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.5-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.6-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.7-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.8-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.9-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.2-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.3-SNAPSHOT//
```

And here is my code

```java
String data = "...."; // the above string
String[] versions = data.split("//");
List<ComparableVersion> comparableVersions = Arrays.stream(versions).map(ComparableVersion::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.sort(comparableVersions);
```

And an error occured

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:422)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:222)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1312)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1506)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1464)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:143)
```

1 I've already tried add different version of maven-artifact dependencies, but all with the same problem.

```
// version 3.8.6 3.8.7 and 3.6.3 are tried
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

2 Using LegacyMergeSort instead of timsort can solve the problem by adding `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` to jvm params, but I don't want it to work on all the array.sort in my project.

So what's wrong with ComparableVersion working with timsort. And how can I find another way to solving this sorting problem. Thanks~

Comment: Which versions of maven-artifact have you tried, and what's the precise dependency?

Comment: First question why do you like to use it? Second as question already which version do you use? A version does not contain `//` ??

Comment: @tgdavies precise dependency and tried version is updated in question.

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry for not expressing clearly,  versions  can be get like this  String[] versions = data.split("//")

Comment: So you have an array of Strings but not an array of ComparableVersions; Every element of the array has to be using the constructor(if I correctly remember) of ComarableVersions and you can sort a list/array of ComparableVersions or there is a method (parseVersion)...

Comment: All the back-and-forth is confusing. Please read [mre]

Comment: @Sören Thanks, I've refined my problem desc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I've add example code on question description.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you don't have any duplicate version numbers which have different string representations:

```
import org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "0.0.1576817712//0.0.3//0.0.4//0.0.4.//0.0.4.1//0.0.4.2//0.0.4.3//0.0.4.4//0.0.4.5//0.0.5//0.0.5.1//0.0.5.2//0.0.5.3//0.0.5.4//0.0.6//0.0.7//0.0.8//0.1.0//0.1.2//0.1.2.1//0.1.2.2//0.1.2.3//0.1.2.4//0.1.2.5//0.1.2.6//0.1.2.7//0.1.2.8//0.1.3//0.1.3.1//0.1.3.2//0.1.3.3//0.1.4//0.1.4.1//0.1.4.2//0.1.4.3//0.1.4.4//0.1.4.5//0.1.4.6//0.1.4.7//0.1.4.8//0.1.4.9//0.1.5//0.1.7//0.1.7.1//0.1.7.2//0.1.7.3//0.1.7.4//0.1.7.5//0.1.7.6//0.1.7.7//0.1.8//0.1.9//0.1.9.1//0.1.9.11//0.1.9.12//0.1.9.13//0.1.9.2//0.1.9.3//0.1.9.8//0.1.9.9//0.1.9.9.1//1.0.0.1//1.0.0.2//1.0.0.3//1.0.0.3.1//1.0.0.4//1.0.0.5//0.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.11-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576066498-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576066912-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576209616-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576677646-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576722159-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576732580-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576737990-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576757185-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576812388-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576817712-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576821661-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576821977-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1576825998-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577182101-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577266235-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577267400-SNAPSHOT//0.0.1577268933-SNAPSHOT//0.0.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.3-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.4.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.11151113-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.2-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.2.1-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.20180829-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.20181115-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.4-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.4.181113-SNAPSHOT//0.0.5.5-SNAPSHOT//0.0.6-SNAPSHOT//0.0.7-SNAPSHOT//0.0.8-SNAPSHOT//0.0.9-SNAPSHOT//0.0.91576063257-SNAPSHOT//0.0.91576066026-SNAPSHOT//0.1.0-SNAPSHOT//0.1.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.2.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.3.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.9-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.l-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.y-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.yl-SNAPSHOT//0.1.4.yy-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5-push-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.5-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.l-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.testpush-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.y-SNAPSHOT//0.1.5.yl-SNAPSHOT//0.1.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.3-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.4-SNAPSHOT//0.1.7.6.1-SNAPSHOT//0.1.8-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.15-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.16-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.6-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.7-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.9.2-SNAPSHOT//0.1.9.9.3-SNAPSHOT//0.2.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.2-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.3-lv-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.3-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.4-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.5-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.6-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.7-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.8-SNAPSHOT//1.0.0.9-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.1-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.2-SNAPSHOT//1.0.1.3-SNAPSHOT"; // the above string
        String[] versions = data.split("//");
        List<ComparableVersion> comparableVersions = Arrays.stream(versions)
                .map(ComparableVersion::new)
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.sort(comparableVersions);
        System.out.println(comparableVersions);
    }
}
```

This assumes that `ComparableVersion.equals()` is not going to return true for any pair of versions which you don't think are equal.

In this case, the latter of `0.0.4` and `0.0.4.` will be removed from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Maven's ComparableVersion comparison algorithm doesn't respect the rule of transitivity, namely: if a < b and b < c then a < c. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract).

Therefore Timsort, which assumes that a comparison algorithm respects transitivity, will not work in many cases.

Here's an example of a test in the Maven repo that will fail since transitivity is not followed:

```
    @Test
    public void transitivity() {
        ComparableVersion c1 = new ComparableVersion("c1");
        ComparableVersion alpha13 = new ComparableVersion("0.0.0-alpha13");
        ComparableVersion allZeroes = new ComparableVersion("0.0.0");

        // A: c1 < 0.0.0-alpha13
        System.out.println(c1.compareTo(alpha13));
        assertTrue(c1.compareTo(alpha13) < 0, "c1 < 0.0.0-alpha13");
        
        // B: 0.0.0-alpha13 < 0.0.0
        System.out.println(alpha13.compareTo(allZeroes));
        assertTrue(alpha13.compareTo(allZeroes) < 0, "0.0.0-alpha13 < 0.0.0");

        // Since c1 < 0.0.0-alpha13 (A) and 0.0.0-alpha13 < 0.0.0 (B), Therefore c1 < 0.0.0
        System.out.println(c1.compareTo(allZeroes));
        assertTrue(c1.compareTo(allZeroes) < 0, "c1 < 0.0.0");
    }
```

The output will be:

```
-1
-5
2

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: c1 < 0.0.0 ==> 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

You could try running your program with the following flag: `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` if you would like your program to not crash (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893487/compile-in-java-6-run-in-7-how-to-specify-uselegacymergesort)), but I believe that the same array may be sorted in different and conflicting ways since transitivity isn't respected.

I would raise an issue for this in the [Maven](https://github.com/apache/maven) repo. But, it doesn't seem like they allow issues.