# Comparison method violates its general contract in Java

Tags: java, android

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
   int search = ((AlbumModel)o).getSearchResult();
   if (search-this.searchResult==0) {
       return ((AlbumModel)o).dateModified-this.dateModified;
   } else {
       return search-this.searchResult;
   }
}
```

I use this code on JDK6 and it works perfectly. But when I try to use the code on JDK 7(++), it throws an Illegal argument exception.

Comment: What is the return type of ```dateModified```? is that ```int```? Can you paste the ```stackTrace()```?

Comment: yea it is int .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison method violates its general contract! Java 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849539/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-java-7-only)