# how to avoid IllegalArgumentException while sorting in android

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

ISSUE [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486605/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-in-java-7) [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234038/compare-method-throw-exception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract) [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441666/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract)

From the above links,i hope i'm following the answers which are accepted.But still i m getting the exception. I'm using Java 6.

code  :

```
public class GenericComparator implements Comparator<User> {

private static final String TAG = "java.util.Comparator.GenericComparator";
EnumComparatorObjectType mType;

public GenericComparator(EnumComparatorObjectType paramType) {

    mType = paramType;
}

@Override
public int compare(User user1, User user2) {

    if (user1 == null && user2 == null)
        return 0;
    try {
        if (mType == EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_ADDRESS_BOOK_ENTRY) {
            String name1 = user1.getUsername();
            String name2 = user2.getUsername();
            return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
        } else if (mType == EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_PRESENCE) {
            EnumPresence p1 = user1.getState();
            EnumPresence p2 = user2.getState();
            return p1.compareTo(p2);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.i(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    return 0;
}

}
```

Stack trace :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:864)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:481)
        at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:422)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:219)
        at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
        at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2038)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1891)
        at com.sample.app.adapters.BuddyListAdapter.filerContacts(BuddyListAdapter.java:144)
        at com.sample.app.adapters.BuddyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BuddyListAdapter.java:126)
        at com.sample.app.HomeActivity$2.onReceive(HomeActivity.java:325)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:763)
        ... 9 more`

Comment: Is the state of either user changing during the sort? If user1 > user2 == true, then user2 <= user1 has to be true too, if the sort tries that later. Have you considered splitting this into two comparators? A UserNameComparator and a UserPresenceComparator?

Comment: When my friends presence changes, i ll be notified and sort by alphabetical first and then presence next.This process continues for every new presence notified.  Collections.sort(mUsers, new GenericComparator(EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_ADDRESS_BOOK_ENTRY));
   Collections.sort(mUsers, new GenericComparator(EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_PRESENCE));

Comment: using two different comparators can solve in my case ?

Comment: If I were you, I'd compare getState() first, if the result equals to 0, I'd then compare getUsername(). Otherwise, return the getState() result.

Comment: @Aprian the same logic applies in link 2 mentioned,where time = presence and voltot = username.is that same you mean ?

Comment: @Meher yeah, that's it. Any reason why you don't use that?

Comment: I was thinking that if the state of anything changed, ie. the sort mode, then the sort algorithm would get confused and throw this exception. A pair of separate Comparators would prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have taken care of the case that *both* entries are `null`, but not the case that one is `null` and the other is not. The problem was hidden by the fact that you used `catch (Exception ...)`, which also catches `NullPointerException`, and then return 0. That means any object compared to `null` returns 0 (meaning `null` and an object are equal), but non-null entries are compared normally. According to this logic, you coult get a[1] == a[2], and a[1] == a[3], but a[2] != a[3]. This is clearly wrong as it wouldn't allow objects to be sorted correctly. This is what the exception message "Comparison method violates its general contract" is trying to say. So I suggest to *not* catch `Exception`.

I suggest to try the following:

```
if (user1 == null || user2 == null) {
    if (user1 == user2) {
        // both are null
        return 0;
    } else if (user1 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    // user2 is null
    return 1;
}
if (mType == EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_ADDRESS_BOOK_ENTRY) {
    String name1 = user1.getUsername();
    String name2 = user2.getUsername();
    return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
} else if (mType == EnumComparatorObjectType.ENUM_OBJECT_PRESENCE) {
    EnumPresence p1 = user1.getState();
    EnumPresence p2 = user2.getState();
    return p1.compareTo(p2);
} else {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + mType);
}
```

If you *first* want to compare by state and *then* by name, you could get rid of `mType`, and the second part (after checking for `null`) would become:

```
EnumPresence p1 = user1.getState();
EnumPresence p2 = user2.getState();
int comp = p1.compareTo(p2);
if (comp != 0) {
    return comp;
}
String name1 = user1.getUsername();
String name2 = user2.getUsername();
return name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2);
```

Comment: @421 did you remove the `try { ... } catch ...` part? It needs to be removed as it hides problems. If you do get an exception while comparing, then please post the stack trace of that exception.

Comment: yes,i removed try-catch earlier.i update your latest answer.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the code correction as shown.The error also lies in handling the array-list,which keeps on changing as presence changes.Now created one more temp arraylist to sort the list.I could not see the error now.