# Collections.sort() throws Comparison method violates its general contract! exception

Tags: java, sorting, exception, collections

I'm trying to sort a List<> object and I get this exception thrown (for large lists only though)

sorting code:

```
List<FinalSentence> sentenceList = finalRepresentation.getSentences();
Collections.sort(sentenceList); // <=== EXCEPTION THROWN HERE!!!
```

FinalSentence class header:

```
public class FinalSentence implements Comparable<FinalSentence>{...}
```

compareTo() implementation:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(FinalSentence o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (this.score > o.score) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (this.score < o.score) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
at feature.finalRepresentation.Summarizer.summarize(Summarizer.java:30)
at driver.Driver.main(Driver.java:114)
```

for a small list (less than 50 elements) it works. for a large list (it's supposed to work with those as well) it throws this exception.
The instance type of the List is ArrayList, not that it should matter.

I have no idea how to get to the bottom of this. The list is full, the elements are of the same type (no polymorphism there) and yet I get this weird exception for large lists.

Any ideas?

Thanks ahead!!!

Comment: What is the `score` field? `int`, `double`?

Comment: Log the call that leads to the exception, or use a debugger.

Comment: it may be a problem that comarison to `null` will return 0

Comment: What do you mean by `if (this == o)`?

Comment: @MarcoForberg comparing to `null` will throw an NPE.

Comment: @Karna this is a shortcut - if comparing the `FinalSentence` to itself then return `0`.

Comment: Do you people ever use google?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626437/why-does-my-compare-method-throw-exception-comparison-method-violates-its-gen
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469308/java-error-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234038/compare-method-throw-exception-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract?rq=1

Comment: @arshajii score is a double value

Comment: @nocgod Ok, try replacing this whole thing with `return Double.compare(score, o.score)` and see if that works.

Comment: @nocgod are you sure score is never NaN?

Comment: @nocgod Sure it can :)

Comment: @arshajii you are right, my bad. Got confused with the LinkedBlockingQueue...

Comment: @EtienneMiret true, forgot, the o.score thingie

Comment: @Etienne Miret I don't think so, I've worked very hard to find all the spots where I could get NaNs and eliminated them.

Comment: @arshajii As simple as it sounds, your method actually worked :) please write it as an answer

Comment: @Eel Lee I did use google, and looked quite a lot on stack overflow, couldn't find the answer, and I still can't find the problem, thos ashajii's solutions seems to work it out somehow.

Comment: could this be a precision issue that is breaking the transitive property of your compareTo method?

Comment: @nocgod See my answer below. I think I know what your issue was.

Comment: The (sub-)question why it fails for large lists only was just answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29866539/1639625). Seems like the cutoff is not 50 but 32, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182700/collections-sort-throws-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-excep?noredirect=1#comment28381311_19182700), [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182700/collections-sort-throws-comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-excep/19183199#comment28380870_19182700) of using

```
Double.compare(score, o.score)
```

fixed the issue. My guess is that there was either a problem with `±0`s or `NaN`s. In fact, if you look at the source of `Double.compare()`, you will find that it's slightly more complicated than you might think, and treats these cases specifically:

```
958    public static int compare(double d1, double d2) {
959        if (d1 < d2)
960            return -1;           // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
961        if (d1 > d2)
962            return 1;            // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger
963
964        long thisBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d1);
965        long anotherBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d2);
966
967        return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
968                (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
969                 1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
970    }
```

([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.compare%28double,double%29))

Moral is: be careful when comparing doubles! :)

---

**Reference:**

- [`Double.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29)

Comment: Yep. His objects probably contain NaNs / -0.0 etc. I initially thought his score was mutated between comparisons before heading over to the compare() method of the `Double` class.

Comment: I've added a check before all the comparisons to check if either values is NaN, it figures I still have some 0/0 or inf/inf problems in the scoring system...thanks for the help, you actually found a bug in my program, now I have to find where it originates...31 metrics here I come :(

Answer (score 4):

It could happen if you break the transitivity rule. If A>B and B>C, then C>A breaks the contract

Comment: Yeah you are right. I didn't notice that some of my values were NaNs (a bug that I found and fixed, now there are no NaNs whatsoever)

Answer (score -4):

Didn't you mean typing:

```
    if (this.score == o.score) {
        return 0;
    }
```

instead of this:

```
    if (this == o) {
        return 0;
    }
```

?

Comment: No, he likely didn't.

Comment: I think he got confused between `o`(O) with `0` (zero). Just like me

Comment: I compare references in case I try to compare an element to it-self

Comment: @Karna He didn't do that either. In fact putting `0` there would make no sense.

Comment: @arshajii `if(this == 0)` ? How?

Comment: @arshajii: It will cause compile time error `Incompatible operand types FinalSentence and int`