# Java Comparable Object Sorting: compareTo(Object) error

Tags: java, sorting, logic, comparable, compareto

I have this compareTo function that continues to, while not always, throw an error regarding its general contract, which if you have done sorting via the Comparable class, have probably hit at some point.

```
public int compareTo(FollowableEntity otherEntity) {
    if(followTarget == null || otherEntity == null || otherEntity.followTarget == null || !otherEntity.follows) return 0;
    if(this.followTarget != otherEntity.followTarget) return 0;
    if(this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) == otherEntity.getDistanceToEntity(followTarget) && this.getDistanceSqToEntity(otherEntity) < this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget)) return 1;
    if(this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) == otherEntity.getDistanceToEntity(followTarget) && this.getDistanceSqToEntity(otherEntity) > this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget)) return -1;
    if(this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) < otherEntity.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) && (this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) < this.getDistanceSqToEntity(otherEntity))) return -1;
    if(this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) < otherEntity.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) && (this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) > this.getDistanceSqToEntity(otherEntity))) return 1;
    if(this.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget) > otherEntity.getDistanceSqToEntity(followTarget)) return 1;

    return 0;

}


FollowableEntity has double position values: posX, posY, posZ.
(FollowableEntity(obj)).getDistanceSqToEntity(FollowableEntity) returns the squared distance between the entities as a double. (x1 - x)^2 + (y1 - y)^2 + (z1 - z)^2.
```

The first two conditions should logically never happen upon comparing, but I put them there anyway.

I'm not sure what conditions cause the error to be thrown, as the only times it is, there happen to be dozens of entities swirling around each other to reach their target.

Here is a portion of the log, my logging utility is rather inefficient.

```
17:23:37 - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
17:23:37 -  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeLo(ComparableTimSort.java:714)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:451)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:376)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:182)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
17:23:37 -  at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:155)
```

After that it points to the line that calls Collections.sort(), but doesn't tell me anything about the compareTo function.

Comment: It would be very useful if you post the error that is throwing.

Comment: If you're trying to implement `Comparable`, note that the signature is a generic, and so at runtime an object of any class could get passed to your `compareTo` method.  Also, the contract for `Comparable` specifically notes that `compareTo(null)` should throw `NullPointerException`, not return "these are equal" (0).

Comment: Like this:
`if(followTarget == null || otherEntity == null || otherEntity.followTarget == null || !otherEntity.follows) throw new NullPointerException();`
`if(this.followTarget != otherEntity.followTarget)  throw new InputMismatchException();`
I can't seem to the code feature to work right

Comment: Have you considered that doing == comparison with doubles can fail? o1.distance(o2) == o2.distance(o1) may not be true.

Comment: I found a flaw in my entire system, it would probably be better to rewrite it from scratch with a different sorting method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced contract violations with `Comparable` some time ago, and it was related to returning contradictory results; chances are that in some cases your method is returning 1 (or -1) for both `object1.compareTo(object2)` and `object2.compareTo(object1)`

You can find a similar problem here.-

[why does my compare method throw exception -- Comparison method violates its general contract!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626437/why-does-my-compare-method-throw-exception-comparison-method-violates-its-gen)