# Cassandra Thrift Error in CustomTThreadPoolServer in logs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I have an error populating the cassandra log and have no idea what it means. 
I have done a bit of googling around, but found no clear reason for it.

Any ideas?

```
ERROR [Thrift:649566] 2014-06-30 08:51:25,914 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 217) Error occurred during processing of message.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

    at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:868)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:485)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Cassandra are you running?
I guess some version of Cassandra has a bug when running Cassandra with JDK 7 due to changed sort algorithm in Arrays.sort and stricter check of Comparator contract in JDK 7.

Could it be [this Cassandra bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6483)?

Thread on SO explaining why the Exception occurs, [Why does my compare method throw exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6626437/964592)