# Why Incorrect Comparator(Java) Does not throw Exception "Comparison method violates general contract"

Tags: java, compare, comparison

I think below implementation of a comprator is wrong. It will got give me a sorted order of Strings. But when i use this implementation to sort a      List 
it does not throw the below exception : 
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!"

Question : Why above Exception is not thrown by 
      Collections.sort(list, new WrongComparator()) 
 method call ?

```
 public class WrongComparator implements Comparator<String> {

   public int compare(String o1, String o2){
     return 1;
   }
 }
```

Comment: It does or does not throw the exception? And what is your question?

Comment: updated the question , please see.

Comment: Why should it throw the exception? How does it violate any "general contract"?

Comment: Because  following is violated ->  instance.compare("A", "B")  = - instance.compare("B", "A")

Comment: OK, I do see that point.

Comment: The problem i am facing is that on "Production" Environment java throws exception for such comparator but on other environments no such error comes.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910304/comparison-method-violates-its-general-contract-is-thrown-only-in-certain-case)

Answer (score 1):

Because IllegalArgumentException is thrown if it's **detected**. It means, that Collections.sort(..) doesn't make special checks on comparator, but if something goes wrong during the sorting (because of a bad comparator), this exception is thrown. Collections.sort() use Tim sort algorithm and comparator check is performed at the end of the merge phase.

**Why don't you get this exception in this particular case?**
Because your collection is already sorted, according to you comparator. Tim's algorithm detects that it's already sorted and doesnt' perform any merge.