# Java's Comparable Interface: Handling null arguments to compareTo()

Tags: java, exception, null, comparable

Writing some classes for a Framework extension, and I have the following code:

```
public class TimeImpl implements Time, Comparable<TimeImpl>, Serializable
{
...
    public int compareTo(TimeImpl other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            throw new ClassCastException("null");
        return Long.valueOf(toSeconds()).compareTo(other.toSeconds());
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward implementation, if you ask me. My question is: as far as I can tell, the javadocs for the Comparable interface say nothing regarding null arguments. Should I bother checking for it? Should I change the type of exception thrown, should I return some other value in that case? How are other people out there handling this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to simplify a null-safe compareTo() implementation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481813/how-to-simplify-a-null-safe-compareto-implementation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparable and Comparator contract with regards to null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858628/comparable-and-comparator-contract-with-regards-to-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is the compareTo method of Integer from java:

```
 public int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) 
 {
    int thisVal = this.value;
    int anotherVal = anotherInteger.value;
    return (thisVal<anotherVal ? -1 : (thisVal==anotherVal ? 0 : 1));
 }
```

why not implement your compareTo method in the way Integer does.

Comment: I've basically gone with something like this. Not sure why I didn't realize that invoking a method on the null pointer would throw the exception I needed, without have to explicitly check for null.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface *does* say something about handling `null` arguments.

> Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null)
>   should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns
>   false.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to throw `NullPointerException` rather than `ClassCastException`.

This convention is also followed by JDK implementations.