# Find max element in Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing, max

I have such simple code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] tab = {2324,1,2,2324,3,45,1,5,0,9,13,2324,1,3,9,8,4,2,1};
        Integer max = 2324;
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int e = 0; e < tab.length; e++) {
                if (tab[e] == max) {
                    indexes.add(new Integer(e));
                    System.out.println("Found max");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The main problem here is I want to find every index in my `tab` where the `max` value is. For now on, it doesnt work - it doesnt display Found max message even once, although it should do it 3 times. Wheres the problem?

Ok, this finally worked, thanks all of you people:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] tab = {2324,1,2,2324,3,45,1,5,0,9,13,2324,1,3,9,8,4,2,1};
        Integer max = 2324;
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int e = 0; e < tab.length; e++) {
                if (tab[e].intValue() == max.intValue()) {
                    indexes.add(Integer.valueOf(e));
                    System.out.println("Found max");
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: One hint. Use Integer.valueOf(...) instead of new Integer() since it is more memory efficient (uses cached values for small numbers).

Comment: I NEED to use Integers, cant just use int.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304767/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-the-list-arraylist

Comment: Integer.valueOf(e) instead of new Integer(e). Semantically the same, but JVM will return pre-cached objects of numbers between -128 and 127

Comment: @Raghunandan: OPs title is misleading. Your linked question has nothing in common to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if (tab[e].intValue() == max.intValue()) {
```

or

```
if (tab[e].intValue() == max) {
```

If you are using Integer object rather than primitive int, then with comparison operator like == , atleast one operand should be primitive one (other will be converted implicitly).

Or you should use `equals` method for equality

Comment: Hmm, strange. Changed it as you suggested but nothing changed.

Comment: @BrianBrown it changed on my system, can you provide the code again what you tried?

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
Integer[] tab = {2324,1,2,2324,3,45,1,5,0,9,13,2324,1,3,9,8,4,2,1};
```

to

```
int[] tab = {2324,1,2,2324,3,45,1,5,0,9,13,2324,1,3,9,8,4,2,1};
```

`Integer` objects are only precached for the values from -128 to 127.

---

If you want to leave it `Integer` you can change

```
if (tab[e] == max) {
```

to

```
if (tab[e].equals(max)) {
```

because it will then check for object equality, and not reference equality.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are comparing with `==` and not `equals`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `==` operator in something that it is not the primitive int, but an instance of class `Integer`. Basically, you are comparing the references of both objects, which are different. Try using :

```
if(tab[e].equals(max))
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem you have is that you are using `Integer`, not `int`  One difference being that as `Integer` is an object `==` compares the references to two different objects. (Not he contents of those objects)

I suggest you use primitives like `int` instead of objects where you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can only compare primitive values with `==`. Since Integer is an object, change `tab[e] == max` to `tab[e].equals(max)`.

Look for [`equals vs ==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Also read: [Java: int vs integer](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.in/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html)

Answer (score 2):

The JVM is caching Integer values.

`==` only works for numbers between -128 and 127

See explanation here: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the three : 1. `tab[e].intValue() == max` or 2. `int max = 2324;` or 3. Use [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class.