# Trying to print the maximum value of the arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist, max

I've sorted my arraylist in descending order and now I want to print the max value. the arraylist contains a student's name and their grade. I want to print the name of the student with the highest grade. I don't need to print their grade. Just the name. this is my code

```
public void printStudent(){

    Collections.sort(studentList);
    Collections.reverse(studentList);
    System.out.println("Best student is: ");
    for (Student s: studentList){
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}
```

Right now this prints the entire list of students and their grades however I just want to print the name of the student with the highest grade and I've tried many things but can't seem to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304767/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-the-list-arraylist

Comment: Basically, your question needs to be reformulated as "How do I get the first item of an array list?", right?

Comment: Do you really need to sort *and* reverse to accomplish this? Is it too hard to just perform one pass with a loop? If you're lazy `Collections.max` is still better. You don't want to optimize prematurely, but I think this is a bit too much for this simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already sorted the Customer in reverse order then the highest grade should be in the first position of your collection.

Do like below.

```
Customer c = customerList.get(0); // getting the first elementt
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

- If you hare sorted a list into ascending order, where is the largest element?
- If you then reverse the list, where is the largest element now?
- How do you get the Nth element of a list?  (Meta-hint ... read the javadoc!)

Comment: This is the only answer that really helps OP to learn instead giving free code to just copy and paste to solve the homework...

Answer (score 3):

Use [Collections.max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) and not sorting.

Comment: This is the right approach in general, but the OP *may* have been instructed to sort and reverse the list ...

Comment: @ZongZhengLi - Why?  This is clearly a beginners programming assignment designed to get the student started on the basics of programming.  Expecting an "optimal" solution (in any sense) is beside the point for a student at this point in their learning.

Comment: @StephenC I agree, there's no need for perfection. But what do you think when a student can sort and reverse a list, but doesn't know how to access a particular element? I'd argue there are better ways to apply sorting and such in an educational context.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Combarable interface setup?
Collections.sort is based on this.

So either you can print customerList.get(customerList.size() - 1) to print the last index in your list.
Or you can print customerList.get(0)

But as I said: This depends on how you compare Customer against each other.